# Shell command to sum integers, one per line?

Tags: shell

I am looking for a command that will accept (as input) multiple lines of text, each line containing a single integer, and output the sum of these integers.

As a bit of background, I have a log file which includes timing measurements. Through grepping for the relevant lines and a bit of `sed` reformatting I can list all of the timings in that file.  I would like to work out the total. I can pipe this intermediate output to any command in order to do the final sum.  I have always used `expr` in the past, but unless it runs in RPN mode I do not think it is going to cope with this (and even then it would be tricky).

How can I get the summation of integers?

Comment: This is very similar to a question I asked a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295781/shortest-command-to-calculate-the-sum-of-a-column-of-output-on-unix

Comment: This question feels like a problem for code golf. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ :)

Answer (score 1640, accepted):

Bit of awk should do it?

```
awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}' mydatafile
```

Note: some versions of awk have some odd behaviours if you are going to be adding anything exceeding 2^31 (2147483647). See comments for more background. One suggestion is to use `printf` rather than `print`:

```
awk '{s+=$1} END {printf "%.0f", s}' mydatafile
```

Comment: There's a lot of awk love in this room! I like how a simple script like this could be modified to add up a second column of data just by changing the $1 to $2

Comment: Whats are the limits on awk? i.e. how many data elements can it process before dieing? or becoming a less preferable approach to using a small c snippet?

Comment: There's not a practical limit, since it will process the input as a stream. So, if it can handle a file of X lines, you can be pretty sure it can handle X+1.

Comment: I once wrote a rudimentary mailing list processer with an awk script run via the vacation utility.  Good times.  :)

Comment: just used this for a: count all documents’ pages script: `ls $@ | xargs -i pdftk {} dump_data | grep NumberOfPages | awk '{s+=$2} END {print s}'`

Comment: Yeah, I was going to mention that you can also pipe the data to awk ... `cat file.csv | cut -d, -f3 | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'`

Comment: How to modify this to work with floats, e.g. lines containing numbers like 123456.789? This snippet is really helpful when grepping through a huge list of files in accounting.

Comment: awk uses double-precision floats, so it should just work. Whether or not floats are appropriate for accounting I'll leave you to judge :)

Comment: To those like me who don't know awk.. check this [link](http://doc.infosnel.nl/quickawk.html) for super-quick introduction

Comment: `awk` breaks for large numbers (note: paste+bc continues to work).

Comment: Be careful, it will not work with numbers greater than 2147483647 (i.e., 2^31), that's because awk uses a 32 bit signed integer representation. Use `awk '{s+=$1} END {printf "%.0f", s}' mydatafile` instead.

Comment: As @GiancarloSportelli says, his solution below is better - no integer overflow in print, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25245025/992887

Comment: I think if you have any question that goes 'I've been looking for a shell command that does X, but I can't find one'.   The first response you or anyone should have is 'have you tried awk?'

Comment: Lol I was using AWK to just extract the interesting number. Now I see that Chrome actually uses almost 2GB total :)

Comment: @GiancarloSportelli I just wanted to add 2 cents. You can use "%ld" on a 64 bit system to keep the number as a 64 bit int, no conversion at all.
`echo "2147483647\n2147483647\n2147483647\n2147483647" | awk '{s+=$1} END {printf("%ld\n", s)}'`

Comment: Unlike other answers, this one works even when there are empty lines in the data.

Comment: Looking at this - how does one 'print' something before the final s variavble is printed ie total $i s

Comment: What happens if there are lines that don't contain numbers among them? How to filter them out?

Comment: Be aware that `awk` has no knowledge of what an integer is. It does all its math in double precision. Hence only all numbers upto  `2^53` are representable. From that point onwards it goes wrong: `awk 'BEGIN{print 2^53-1, 2^53, 2^53+1}' =>
9007199254740991 9007199254740992 9007199254740992`

Comment: paste/bc from the comment below seems like the correct answer

Comment: Can validate this fairly straightforwardly `seq $((1 << 32)) $(((1 << 32)+10)) | awk '{x+=$1} END {printf "%ld\n", x}' ` output: 47244640311

Comment: Actually Python is my preferred way, because it sums the numbers without rounding the result even for very large numbers, while awk rounds the result.

Comment: Much easier to remember and type than the paste solution.

Comment: @BC : i ran that exact command, even using GMP, and got something waaaaay off : ::::::::::::::: seq $((1 << 32)) $(((1 << 32)+10)) | gawk -Me '{x+=$1} END {printf "%ld\n", x}':::::::::::::::::
5153964000. seq only worked after explicitly  adding formatting flag :::: seq -f '%.f'  flag

Comment: @BrianChrisman : but you don't need the %ld to get it work - any non-mawk.1.3.4 works as is, and mawk-1 just set CONVFMT='%.f' before you begin. but if you try to use "%ld" (as in L ) in mawk-1, I got 4766497255625457664 instead

Comment: yeah.. there are some details on macos/linux as well. ```seq -f '%.0f' $((1 << 32)) $(((1 << 32)+10)) | awk '{x+=$1} END {print x}' ``` where 'seq' can give exponential notation as default on some systems.

Comment: just change the printing mode and it prints fine ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: `jot 574998 - - 54321 | mawk '$++NF=_+=$!_' CONVFMT='%.f' | gtail -n 2` :::::: `31234357717 8979830992388423` ::: `31234412038 8979862226800461`

Answer (score 789):

Paste typically merges lines of multiple files, but it can also be used to convert individual lines of a file into a single line.  The delimiter flag allows you to pass a x+x type equation to bc.

```
paste -s -d+ infile | bc
```

Alternatively, when piping from stdin,

```
<commands> | paste -s -d+ - | bc
```

Comment: Very nice!  I would have put a space before the "+", just to help me parse it better, but that was very handy for piping some memory numbers through paste & then bc.

Comment: A solution using bc or dc is what I was looking for as a solution to my own similar problem.  I don't know much about it and it seems to be underutilized, so it's very good to see others know how to use it.  I suspect it's much faster than the other solutions, especially if there are many lines in the input.

Comment: Much easier to remember and type than the awk solution. Also, note that `paste` can use a dash `-` as the filename - which will allow you to pipe the numbers from the output of a command into paste's standard output without the need to create a file first: `<commands> | paste -sd+ - | bc`

Comment: I find this solution less of an overkill than using a fully-fledged programming language, like awk/perl/python. Kudos!

Comment: Awesome! Just used this to sum bogomips across all cores: cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep bogo | cut -d: -f2 | paste -sd+ | bc

Comment: I have a file with 100 million numbers. The awk command takes 21s; the paste command takes 41s. But good to meet 'paste' nevertheless!

Comment: @Abhi:  Interesting :D  I guess it would take me 20s to figure out the awk command so it evens out though until I try 100 million and one numbers :D

Comment: @Abhi: check the answer. `awk` fails for large numbers on my machine but `paste` + `bc` work.

Comment: @George You can leave out the `-`, though. (It is useful if you wanted to combine a file *with* stdin).

Comment: This didn't like the '^m' chars in the file, but once that was fixed, happy happy.

Comment: @AloisMahdal You can't leave out the `-` when used in pipe. `echo -e "1\n2\n3" | paste -sd+` doesn't work, but having the extra `-` does work.

Comment: @MarkKCowan `bc` uses arbitrary precision, I guess `awk` is likely to use 32 or 64-bit arithmetics, possibly leading to overflows.

Comment: @Causality then it's probably version-dependent; it does work here with GNU coreutils 8.24 (Fedora 23); your code in last comment yields `1+2+3`

Comment: Note that `bc` isn't included in some shells, like Git Bash for Windows.

Comment: @10basetom that's because `bc` is not a shell-builtin (so it's not included in any shell) but a separate program (which is pretty standard on any un*x machine)

Comment: @umläute I know why it's not included in some shells -- I was pointing that out so that people can consider alternative solutions if their aim is portability.

Comment: had the problem that bc was not installed and ended up with `echo $(( $( <commands> | paste -s -d+ -) ))` to evaluate the answer

Comment: @George and @Abhi ... so the `awk` solution is both easier to remember... and faster. double win.

Comment: paste & bc also, like Python, sums the numbers without rounding the result even for very large numbers, while awk rounds the result.

Answer (score 156):

The one-liner version in Python:

```
$ python -c "import sys; print(sum(int(l) for l in sys.stdin))"
```

Comment: Above one-liner doesn't work for files in sys.argv[], but that one does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450799/linux-command-to-sum-integers-one-per-line#450825

Comment: True- the author said he was going to pipe output from another script into the command and I was trying to make it as short as possible :)

Comment: Shorter version would be `python -c"import sys; print(sum(map(int, sys.stdin)))"`

Comment: I love this answer for its ease of reading and flexibility. I needed the average size of files smaller than 10Mb in a collection of directories and modified it to this: `find . -name '*.epub' -exec stat -c %s '{}' \; | python -c "import sys; nums = [int(n) for n in sys.stdin if int(n) < 10000000]; print(sum(nums)/len(nums))"`

Comment: Very flexible solution. Also usable for float numbers, just replace `int` with `float`

Comment: You can also filter out non numbers if you have some text mixed in: `import sys; print(sum(int(''.join(c for c in l if c.isdigit())) for l in sys.stdin))`

Comment: Actually Python is my preferred way, because it sums the numbers without rounding the result even for very large numbers, while awk rounds the result.

Comment: @jfs : use gawk -M bignum mode with GMP, and nothing fails

Answer (score 127):

I would put a big WARNING on the commonly approved solution:

```
awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}' mydatafile # DO NOT USE THIS!!
```

that is because in this form awk uses a 32 bit signed integer representation: it will overflow for sums that exceed 2147483647 (i.e., 2^31).

A more general answer (for summing integers) would be:

```
awk '{s+=$1} END {printf "%.0f\n", s}' mydatafile # USE THIS INSTEAD
```

Comment: Why does printf() help here? The overflow of the int will have happened before that because the summing code is the same.

Comment: Because the problem is actually in the "print" function. Awk uses 64 bit integers, but for some reason print donwscales them to 32 bit.

Comment: The print bug appears to be fixed, at least for awk 4.0.1 & bash 4.3.11, unless I'm mistaken: `echo -e "2147483647 \n 100" |awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}'` shows `2147483747`

Comment: Using floats just introduces a new problem: `echo 999999999999999999 | awk '{s+=$1} END {printf "%.0f\n", s}'` produces `1000000000000000000`

Comment: Shouldn't just using "%ld" on 64bit systems work to not have printf truncate to 32bit? As @Patrick points out, floats aren't a great idea here.

Comment: @yerforkferchips, where should `%ld` be placed in the code? I tried `echo -e "999999999999999999" | awk '{s+=$1} END {printf "%ld\n", s}'` but it still produced `1000000000000000000`.

Comment: See the latest comment by @kvantour on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/450821/3090225 -- a sad fact in awk ;)

Comment: Both methods print the same number, even with large numbers (40 decimal digits), but they are both not accurate - only about the first 15 digits are accurate and the rest are random.

Comment: As others said awk is incompatible with itself across different versions and builds. You need to be aware of what to really expect with such operations, each time...

Comment: @Uri : then just track the addition using a hi/lo combo of 2 integers. Between 2 of them, you can easily track 101-102 bits to full precision. Track with 5 integers total, and you'll be jus shy of 256-bit full precision. Use 21 of them, and you can even track unsigned 1024-bit without needing arrays

Answer (score 101):

With [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
seq 10 | jq -s 'add' # 'add' is equivalent to 'reduce .[] as $item (0; . + $item)'
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with `rq`?

Comment: I think I know what could be the next question, so I will add the answer here :) **calculate average:** `seq 10 | jq -s 'add / length'`  [ref here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Variable/SymbolicBindingOperator:...as$identifier|...)

Comment: this is slow. `jq -s 'add'` is 8x slower than the C version

Answer (score 97):

Plain bash:

```
$ cat numbers.txt 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
$ sum=0; while read num; do ((sum += num)); done < numbers.txt; echo $sum
55
```

Comment: A smaller one liner: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450799/linux-command-to-sum-integers-one-per-line/7720597#7720597

Comment: @rjack, where is `num` defined? I believe somehow it is connected to the `< numbers.txt` expression, but it is not clear how.

Comment: @Atcold `num` is defined in the while expression. `while read XX` means "use `while` to read a value, then store that value in `XX`"

Comment: this is slow, 100x slower than the C version

Answer (score 72):

```
dc -f infile -e '[+z1<r]srz1<rp'
```

Note that negative numbers prefixed with minus sign should be translated for `dc`, since  it uses `_` prefix rather than `-` prefix for that. For example, via `tr '-' '_' | dc -f- -e '...'`.

#### Edit: Since this answer got so many votes "for obscurity", here is a detailed explanation:

The expression `[+z1<r]srz1<rp` [does the following](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dc):

```
[   interpret everything to the next ] as a string
  +   push two values off the stack, add them and push the result
  z   push the current stack depth
  1   push one
  <r  pop two values and execute register r if the original top-of-stack (1)
      is smaller
]   end of the string, will push the whole thing to the stack
sr  pop a value (the string above) and store it in register r
z   push the current stack depth again
1   push 1
<r  pop two values and execute register r if the original top-of-stack (1)
    is smaller
p   print the current top-of-stack
```

As pseudo-code:

1. Define "add_top_of_stack" as:

   1. Remove the two top values off the stack and add the result back
   2. If the stack has two or more values, run "add_top_of_stack" recursively
2. If the stack has two or more values, run "add_top_of_stack"
3. Print the result, now the only item left in the stack

To really understand the simplicity and power of `dc`, here is a working Python script that implements some of the commands from `dc` and executes a Python version of the above command:

```
### Implement some commands from dc
registers = {'r': None}
stack = []
def add():
    stack.append(stack.pop() + stack.pop())
def z():
    stack.append(len(stack))
def less(reg):
    if stack.pop() < stack.pop():
        registers[reg]()
def store(reg):
    registers[reg] = stack.pop()
def p():
    print stack[-1]

### Python version of the dc command above

# The equivalent to -f: read a file and push every line to the stack
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    stack.append(int(line.strip()))

def cmd():
    add()
    z()
    stack.append(1)
    less('r')

stack.append(cmd)
store('r')
z()
stack.append(1)
less('r')
p()
```

Comment: dc is just the tool of choice to use. But I would do it with a little less stack ops. Assumed that all lines really contain a number: `(echo "0"; sed 's/$/ +/' inp; echo 'pq')|dc`.

Comment: The online algorithm: `dc -e '0 0 [+?z1<m]dsmxp'`. So we don't save all the numbers on stack before processing but read and process them one by one (to be more precise, line by line, since one line can contain several numbers). Note that empty line can terminate an input sequence.

Comment: @ikrabbe that's great. It can actually be shortened by one more character: the space in the `sed` substitution can be removed, as `dc`  doesn't care about spaces between arguments and operators. `(echo "0"; sed 's/$/+/' inputFile; echo 'pq')|dc`

Comment: this is slow. `dc -f - -e '[+z1<r]srz1<rp'` is 250x slower than the C version. `dc -e '0 0 [+?z1<m]dsmxp'` is 15x slower than the C version

Answer (score 53):

Pure and short bash.

```
f=$(cat numbers.txt)
echo $(( ${f//$'\n'/+} ))
```

Comment: This is the best solution because it does not create any subprocess if you replace first line with `f=$(<numbers.txt)`.

Comment: any way of having the input from stdin ? like from a pipe ?

Comment: @njzk2 If you put `f=$(cat); echo $(( ${f//$'\n'/+} ))` in a script, then you can pipe anything to that script or invoke it without arguments for interactive stdin input (terminate with Control-D).

Comment: @loentar The `<numbers.txt` is an improvement, but, overall, this solution is only efficient for small input files; for instance, with a file of 1,000 input lines the accepted `awk` solution is about 20 times faster on my machine - and also consumes less memory, because the file is not read all at once.

Comment: My usecease: f=$(find -iname '\*-2014-\*' -exec du {} \; | cut -f1); echo $(( ${f//$'\n'/+} )). Might help someone.

Comment: An advantage of the bash solution over the awk solution is that it gives an integer result, even for large numbers.  For large numbers, awk returns a result in scientific notation.

Comment: This answer is not pure bash because `cat` is an external call. See the accepted answer's `awk '{s+=$1}END{printf"%f",s}' mydatafile` for a faster solution that won't fail given too large an input. Load time differences (`cat`'s 43k vs `mawk`'s 128k or even `gawk`'s 659k on my system) won't ever overcome the performance difference ... unless you're running this too often, in which case use more `awk` or else a "real" language.

Comment: i didn't downvote, but wanna note this is a horrific solution - summing up from 1 to `99999` took 26.7 seconds on a machine with M1 Max and `bash 5.2.15`, versus  `0.053 secs` on `awk` using `jot`, and `0.22 secs` generating via another `awk`.  Even summing every integer to 100 mil was only 11.5 seconds, and just 1 min 55secs summing all the way to 1 billion. `perl` came in *just* slower than `awk`

Answer (score 43):

```
perl -lne '$x += $_; END { print $x; }' < infile.txt
```

Comment: And I added them back: "-l" ensures that output is LF-terminated as shell `` backticks and most programs expect, and "<" indicates this command can be used in a pipeline.

Comment: You are right. As an excuse: Each character in Perl one-liners requires a mental work for me, therefore I prefer to strip as many characters as possible. The habit was harmful in this case.

Comment: One of the few solutions that doesn't load everything into RAM.

Comment: I find it curious just how undervalued this answer is in comparison with the top-rated ones (that use non-shell tools) -- while it's faster and simpler than those.  It's almost the same syntax as awk but faster (as benchmarked in another well-voted answer here) and without any caveats, and it's much shorter and simpler than python, and faster (flexibility can be added just as easily).  One needs to know the basics of the language used for it, but that goes for any tool. I get the notion of a popularity of a tool but this question is tool agnostic.  All these were published the same day.

Comment: (disclaimer for my comment above: I know and use and like Perl and Python, as good tools.)

Comment: @zdim : no idea what you're benchmarking with or against, but i just summed `1` to `99,999,999`, and `perl 5.36` came in *just* behind `mawk 1.9.9.6`

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto  That was written a year and a half ago, but according to the comment itself I was quoting a ("well-quoted") benchmark posted on this page (I didn't benchmark anything) ...?  (Did you actually read my comment?).  I don't know how `mawk` does it or how you timed things, but yes awk can be speedy for many things, agreed.

Answer (score 38):

My fifteen cents:

```
$ cat file.txt | xargs  | sed -e 's/\ /+/g' | bc
```

Example:

```
$ cat text
1
2
3
3
4
5
6
78
9
0
1
2
3
4
576
7
4444
$ cat text | xargs  | sed -e 's/\ /+/g' | bc 
5148
```

Comment: My input could contain blank lines, so I used what you posted here plus a `grep -v '^$'`. Thanks!

Comment: wow!! your answer is amazing!
my personal favorite from all in the tread

Comment: Love this and +1 for pipeline. Very simple and easy solution for me

Answer (score 38):

I've done a quick benchmark on the existing answers which

- use only standard tools (sorry for stuff like `lua` or `rocket`),
- are real one-liners,
- are capable of adding huge amounts of numbers (100 million), and
- are fast (I ignored the ones which took longer than a minute).

I always added the numbers of 1 to 100 million which was doable on my machine in less than a minute for several solutions.

Here are the results:

#### Python

```
:; seq 100000000 | python -c 'import sys; print sum(map(int, sys.stdin))'
5000000050000000
# 30s
:; seq 100000000 | python -c 'import sys; print sum(int(s) for s in sys.stdin)'
5000000050000000
# 38s
:; seq 100000000 | python3 -c 'import sys; print(sum(int(s) for s in sys.stdin))'
5000000050000000
# 27s
:; seq 100000000 | python3 -c 'import sys; print(sum(map(int, sys.stdin)))'
5000000050000000
# 22s
:; seq 100000000 | pypy -c 'import sys; print(sum(map(int, sys.stdin)))'
5000000050000000
# 11s
:; seq 100000000 | pypy -c 'import sys; print(sum(int(s) for s in sys.stdin))'
5000000050000000
# 11s
```

#### Awk

```
:; seq 100000000 | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
5000000050000000
# 22s
```

#### Paste & Bc

This ran out of memory on my machine.  It worked for half the size of the input (50 million numbers):

```
:; seq 50000000 | paste -s -d+ - | bc
1250000025000000
# 17s
:; seq 50000001 100000000 | paste -s -d+ - | bc
3750000025000000
# 18s
```

So I guess it would have taken ~35s for the 100 million numbers.

#### Perl

```
:; seq 100000000 | perl -lne '$x += $_; END { print $x; }'
5000000050000000
# 15s
:; seq 100000000 | perl -e 'map {$x += $_} <> and print $x'
5000000050000000
# 48s
```

#### Ruby

```
:; seq 100000000 | ruby -e "puts ARGF.map(&:to_i).inject(&:+)"
5000000050000000
# 30s
```

#### C

Just for comparison's sake I compiled the C version and tested this also, just to have an idea how much slower the tool-based solutions are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    long sum = 0;
    long i = 0;
    while(scanf("%ld", &i) == 1) {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
    printf("%ld\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

```
:; seq 100000000 | ./a.out 
5000000050000000
# 8s
```

#### Conclusion

C is of course fastest with 8s, but **the Pypy solution only adds a very little overhead of about 30% to 11s**.  But, to be fair, Pypy isn't exactly standard.  Most people only have CPython installed which is significantly slower (22s), exactly as fast as the popular Awk solution.

**The fastest solution based on standard tools is Perl (15s).**

Comment: The `paste` + `bc` approach was just what I was looking for to sum hex values, thanks!

Comment: Just for fun, in Rust: `use std::io::{self, BufRead};
  
fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut sum: i64 = 0;
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        sum += line.unwrap().parse::<i64>().unwrap();
    }
    println!("{}", sum);
}`

Comment: awesome answer. not to nitpick but it is the case that if you decided to include those longer-running results, the answer would be *even more awesome!*

Comment: @StevenLu I felt the answer would just be _longer_ and thus _less awesome_ (to use your words).  But I can understand that this feeling needs not be shared by everybody :)

Comment: Next: numba + parallelisation

Comment: awk would have matched perl if you had used `$0` instead of `$1`

Comment: `datamash sum 1` is maybe 5% slower than the C version

Comment: parallelization: this only works with files, because we cannot seek in a stream. i started a [sum-parallel.c](https://github.com/milahu/sum-parallel) but im not quite there yet...

Answer (score 29):

Using the [*GNU* `datamash` util](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
seq 10 | datamash sum 1
```

Output:

```
55
```

---

If the input data is irregular, with spaces and tabs at odd places, this may confuse `datamash`, then either use the `-W` switch:

```
<commands...> | datamash -W sum 1
```

...or use `tr` to clean up the whitespace:

```
<commands...> | tr -d '[[:blank:]]' | datamash sum 1
```

---

If the input is large enough, the output will be in scientific notation.

```
seq 100000000 | datamash sum 1
```

Output:

```
5.00000005e+15
```

To convert that to decimal, use the the `--format` option:

```
seq 100000000 | datamash  --format '%.0f' sum 1
```

Output:

```
5000000050000000
```

Comment: This works great with my github CLI pagination counting <3

Comment: limitation: datamash works only with streams, not with files, so it will use only one CPU core, no parallelization

Answer (score 20):

BASH solution, if you want to make this a command (e.g. if you need to do this frequently):

```
addnums () {
  local total=0
  while read val; do
    (( total += val ))
  done
  echo $total
}
```

Then usage:

```
addnums < /tmp/nums
```

Answer (score 20):

Plain bash one liner

```
$ cat > /tmp/test
1 
2 
3 
4 
5
^D

$ echo $(( $(cat /tmp/test | tr "\n" "+" ) 0 ))
```

Comment: No _cat_ needed:  `echo $(( $( tr "\n" "+"  < /tmp/test) 0 ))`

Comment: `tr` isn't exactly "plain Bash" /nitpick

Answer (score 17):

You can using num-utils, although it may be overkill for what you need. This is a set of programs for manipulating numbers in the shell, and can do several nifty things, including of course, adding them up. It's a bit out of date, but they still work and can be useful if you need to do something more.

https://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/index.phtml

It's really simple to use:

```
$ seq 10 | numsum
55
```

But runs out of memory for large inputs.

```
$ seq 100000000 | numsum
Terminado (killed)
```

Comment: Example: `numsum numbers.txt`.

Comment: Example with pipe: `printf "%s\n" 1 3 5 | numsum`

Answer (score 15):

Cannot avoid submitting this, it is the most generic approach to this Question, please check:

```
jot 1000000 | sed '2,$s/$/+/;$s/$/p/' | dc
```

It is to be found over here, I was the OP and the answer came from the audience:

- [Most elegant unix shell one-liner to sum list of numbers of arbitrary precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44771056/which-is-the-most-elegant-unix-shell-one-liner-to-sum-any-numbers-of-arbitrary-p/46248951#46248951)

And here are its special advantages over **awk**, **bc**, **perl**, **GNU's datamash** and friends:

- it uses standards utilities common in any unix environment
- it does not depend on buffering and thus it does not choke with really long inputs.
- it implies no particular precision limits -or integer size for that matter-, hello AWK friends!
- no need for different code, if floating point numbers need to be added, instead.
- it theoretically runs unhindered in the minimal of environments

Comment: Please include the code related to the question in the answer and not refer to a link

Comment: It also happens to be much slower than all the other solutions, more than 10 times slower than the datamash solution

Comment: @GabrielRavier OP doesn't define speed as a first requirement, so in absence of that a generic working solution would be preferred. FYI. datamash is not standard across all Unix platforms, fi. MacOSX appears to be lacking that.

Comment: @fgeorgatos this is true, but I just wanted to point out to everyone else looking at this question that this answer is, in fact, very slow compared to what you can get on most Linux systems.

Comment: @GabrielRavier could you provide some measured numbers for comparison?

btw. I have run a couple of `jot` tests and speed is very reasonable even for quite large lists. btw. if datamash is taken as the solution to the OP's question, then any compiled assembly program should be acceptable, too... that would speed it up!

Comment: @fgeorgatos After some calculations, I can confirm it is even more than 10 times faster. `time seq 10000000 | sed '2,$s/$/+/;$s/$/p/' | dc` gives me the correct result in 43 seconds whereas `time seq 10000000 | datamash sum 1` does it in 1 second, making it more than 40 times faster. Also, a "compiled assembly program" as you call it, would be much more convoluted a solution, likely not much faster and would be much more likely to give incorrect solutions

Answer (score 12):

```
sed 's/^/.+/' infile | bc | tail -1
```

Answer (score 12):

I realize this is an old question, but I like this solution enough to share it.

```
% cat > numbers.txt
1 
2 
3 
4 
5
^D
% cat numbers.txt | perl -lpe '$c+=$_}{$_=$c'
15
```

If there is interest, I'll explain how it works.

Comment: Please don't. We like to pretend that -n and -p are nice semantic things, not just some clever string pasting ;)

Comment: Yes please, do explain :)  (I'm not a Perl typea guy.)

Comment: Try running "perl -MO=Deparse -lpe '$c+=$_}{$_=$c'" and looking at the  output, basically -l uses newlines and both input and output separators, and -p prints each line.  But in order to do '-p', perl first adds some boiler plate (which -MO=Deparse) will show you, but then it just substitutes and compiles.  You can thus cause an extra block to be inserted with the '}{' part and trick it into not printing on each line, but print at the very end.

Answer (score 11):

The following works in bash:

```
I=0

for N in `cat numbers.txt`
do
    I=`expr $I + $N`
done

echo $I
```

Comment: Command expansion should be used with caution when files can be arbitrarily large.
With numbers.txt of 10MB, the `cat numbers.txt` step would be problematic.

Comment: Indeed, however (if not for the better solutions found here) I would use this one until I actually encountered that problem.

Answer (score 8):

Pure bash and in a one-liner :-)

```
$ cat numbers.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10


$ I=0; for N in $(cat numbers.txt); do I=$(($I + $N)); done; echo $I
55
```

Comment: Why are there two `((` parenthesis `))`?

Comment: Not really pure bash due to cat. make it pure bash by replacing cat with `$(< numbers.txt)`

Answer (score 6):

Alternative pure Perl, fairly readable, no packages or options required:

```
perl -e "map {$x += $_} <> and print $x" < infile.txt
```

Comment: or a tiny bit shorter:

     perl -e 'map {$x += $_} <>; print $x' infile.txt

Comment: Memory required is almost 2GB for a large input of 10 million numbers

Answer (score 6):

For Ruby Lovers

```
ruby -e "puts ARGF.map(&:to_i).inject(&:+)" numbers.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a nice and clean [Raku](https://raku.org/) (formerly known as Perl 6) one-liner:

```raku
say [+] slurp.lines
```

We can use it like so:

```bash
% seq 10 | raku -e "say [+] slurp.lines"
55
```

It works like this:

[`slurp`](https://docs.raku.org/language/independent-routines#sub_slurp) without any arguments reads from standard input by default; it returns a string. Calling the [`lines` method](https://docs.raku.org/routine/lines#(Str)_routine_lines) on a string returns a list of lines of the string.

The brackets around `+` turn `+` into a [reduction meta operator](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Reduction_metaoperators) which *reduces* the list to a single value: the sum of the values in the list. `say` then prints it to standard output with a newline.

One thing to note is that we never explicitly convert the lines to numbers—Raku is smart enough to do that for us. However, this means our code breaks on input that definitely isn't a number:

```bash
% echo "1\n2\nnot a number" | raku -e "say [+] slurp.lines"
Cannot convert string to number: base-10 number must begin with valid digits or '.' in '⏏not a number' (indicated by ⏏)
  in block <unit> at -e line 1
```

Comment: `say [+] lines` is actually enough  :-)

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen: cool! how does that work?

Comment: `lines` without any arguments has the same semantics as `slurp` without any semantics, but it produces a `Seq` of `Str`, rather than a single `Str`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in python, if you feel comfortable:

Not tested, just typed:

```
out = open("filename").read();
lines = out.split('\n')
ints = map(int, lines)
s = sum(ints)
print s
```

Sebastian pointed out a one liner script:

```
cat filename | python -c"from fileinput import input; print sum(map(int, input()))"
```

Comment: python -c"from fileinput import input; print sum(map(int, input()))" numbers.txt

Comment: cat is overused, redirect stdin from file:
python -c "..." < numbers.txt

Comment: @rjack: `cat` is used to demonstrate that script works both for stdin and for files in argv[] (like `while(<>)` in Perl). If your input is in a file then '<' is unnecessary.

Comment: But `< numbers.txt` demonstrates that it works on stdin just as well as `cat numbers.txt |` does.  And it doesn't teach bad habits.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov If you care so much about habits, using the notation `command < file` is a bad habit itself. Use `< file command` instead. Bash one-liners should be easy to read left-to-right from input to output.

Answer (score 4):

The following should work (assuming your number is the second field on each line).

```
awk 'BEGIN {sum=0} \
 {sum=sum + $2} \
END {print "tot:", sum}' Yourinputfile.txt
```

Comment: You don't really need the {sum=0} part

Answer (score 4):

C (not simplified)

```
seq 1 10 | tcc -run <(cat << EOF
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(scanf("%d", &i) == 1) {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
EOF)
```

Comment: I had to upvote the comment. There's nothing wrong with the answer - it's quite good. However, to show that the comment makes the answer awesome, I'm just upvoting the comment.

Comment: impressive, this has the same performance as the gcc-compiled C version

Comment: nitpick: `int` should be `long`. there should be a newline between `EOF` and `)`

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat n
2
4
2
7
8
9
```

```
$ perl -MList::Util -le 'print List::Util::sum(<>)' < n
32
```

Or, you can type in the numbers on the command line:

```
$ perl -MList::Util -le 'print List::Util::sum(<>)'
1
3
5
^D
9
```

However, this one slurps the file so it is not a good idea to use on large files. See [j_random_hacker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450799/linux-command-to-sum-integers-one-per-line/450819#450819) which avoids slurping.

Answer (score 3):

One-liner in Racket:

```
racket -e '(define (g) (define i (read)) (if (eof-object? i) empty (cons i (g)))) (foldr + 0 (g))' < numlist.txt
```

Comment: this is slow, 25x slower than the C version

Answer (score 3):

My version:

```
seq -5 10 | xargs printf "- - %s" | xargs  | bc
```

Comment: Shorter: `seq -s+ -5 10  | bc`

Answer (score 2):

C++ (simplified):

```
echo {1..10} | scc 'WRL n+=$0; n'
```

SCC project - http://volnitsky.com/project/scc/

SCC is C++ snippets evaluator at shell prompt

Comment: link is gone. this works: https://github.com/lvv/scc

Answer (score 2):

Apologies in advance for readability of the backticks ("`"), but these work in shells other than bash and are thus more pasteable.  If you use a shell which accepts it, the $(command ...) format is much more readable (and thus debuggable) than `command ...` so feel free to modify for your sanity.

I have a simple function in my bashrc that will use awk to calculate a number of simple math items

```
calc(){
  awk 'BEGIN{print '"$@"' }'
}
```

This will do +,-,*,/,^,%,sqrt,sin,cos, parenthesis ....(and more depending on your version of awk) ... you could even get fancy with printf and format floating point output, but this is all I normally need

for this particular question, I would simply do this for each line:

```
calc `echo "$@"|tr " " "+"`
```

so the code block to sum each line would look something like this:

```
while read LINE || [ "$LINE" ]; do
  calc `echo "$LINE"|tr " " "+"` #you may want to filter out some lines with a case statement here
done
```

That's if you wanted to only sum them line by line.  However for a total of *every* number in the datafile

```
VARS=`<datafile`
calc `echo ${VARS// /+}`
```

btw if I need to do something quick on the desktop, I use this:

```
xcalc() { 
  A=`calc "$@"`
  A=`Xdialog --stdout --inputbox "Simple calculator" 0 0 $A`
  [ $A ] && xcalc $A
}
```

Comment: What kind of ancient shell are you using that doesn't support `$()`?

Answer (score 2):

Real-time summing to let you monitor progress of some number-crunching task.

```
$ cat numbers.txt 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

$ cat numbers.txt | while read new; do total=$(($total + $new)); echo $total; done
1
3
6
10
15
21
28
36
45
55
```

(There is no need to set `$total` to zero in this case. Neither you can access $total after the finish.)

Answer (score 1):

A lua interpreter is present on all fedora-based systems [fedora,RHEL,CentOS,korora etc. because it is embedded with rpm-package(the package of package manager rpm), i.e rpm-lua] and if u want to learn lua this kind of problems are ideal(you'll get your job done as well).

```
cat filname | lua -e "sum = 0;for i in io.lines() do sum=sum+i end print(sum)"
```

and it works. Lua is verbose though, you might have to endure some repeated keyboard stroke injury :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Alacon - command-line utility for [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) database.

It works with Node.js, so you need to install [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and then [Alasql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/alasql) package:

To calculate sum from stdin you can use the following command:

```
> cat data.txt | node alacon "SELECT VALUE SUM([0]) FROM TXT()" >b.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your preferred 'expr' command you just need to finagle the input a little first:

```
seq 10 | tr '[\n]' '+' | sed -e 's/+/ + /g' -e's/ + $/\n/' | xargs expr
```

The process is:

- "tr" replaces the eoln characters with a + symbol,
- sed pads the '+' with spaces on each side, and then strips the final + from the line
- xargs inserts the piped input into the command line for expr to consume.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, there is also an `R` solution

```
seq 1 10 | R -q -e "f <- file('stdin'); open(f); cat(sum(as.numeric(readLines(f))))"
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED BENCHMARKS**

So I synthetically generated `100 mn` integers randomly distributed

between

```
0^0 - 1
```

and

```
8^8 - 1
```

**GENERATOR CODE**

```
mawk2 '
BEGIN {
     __=_=((_+=_^=_<_)+(__=_*_*_))^(___=__)
     srand()
     ___^=___
     do  { 
           print int(rand()*___) 
  
     } while(--_)  }' | pvE9 > test_large_int_100mil_001.txt

     out9:  795MiB 0:00:11 [69.0MiB/s] [69.0MiB/s] [ <=> ]

  f='test_large_int_100mil_001.txt'
  wc5 < "${f}"

    rows = 100000000. | UTF8 chars = 833771780. | bytes = 833771780.
```

**Odd / Even distribution of Last Digit**

```
Odd  49,992,332
Even 50,007,668
```

**AWK - Fastest, by a good margin (maybe C is faster I dunno)**

```
in0:  795MiB 0:00:07 [ 103MiB/s] [ 103MiB/s] [============>] 100%            
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${f}" | mawk2 '{ _+=$__ } END { print _ }'; )  

 7.64s user 0.35s system 103% cpu 7.727 total
     1  838885279378716
```

**Perl - Quite Decent**

```
 in0:  795MiB 0:00:10 [77.6MiB/s] [77.6MiB/s] [==============>] 100%            
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${f}" | perl -lne '$x += $_; END { print $x; }'; )  
 
10.16s user 0.37s system 102% cpu 10.268 total

     1  838885279378716
```

**Python3 - Slightly behind Perl**

```
 in0:  795MiB 0:00:11 [71.5MiB/s] [71.5MiB/s] [===========>] 100%            
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${f}" | python3 -c ; )  

 11.00s user 0.43s system 102% cpu 11.140 total
     1  838885279378716
```

**RUBY - Decent**

```
 in0:  795MiB 0:00:13 [61.0MiB/s] [61.0MiB/s] [===========>] 100%            
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${f}" | ruby -e 'puts ARGF.map(&:to_i).inject(&:+)'; )  
15.30s user 0.70s system 101% cpu 15.757 total

     1  838885279378716
```

**JQ - Slow**

```
 in0:  795MiB 0:00:25 [31.1MiB/s] [31.1MiB/s] [========>] 100%            
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${f}" | jq -s 'add'; )  

 36.95s user 1.09s system 100% cpu 37.840 total

     1  838885279378716
```

**DC**

```
- ( had to kill it after no response in minutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

one simple solution would be to write a program to do it for you.  This could probably be done pretty quickly in python, something like:

```
sum = 0
file = open("numbers.txt","R")
for line in file.readlines(): sum+=int(line)
file.close()
print sum
```

I haven't tested that code, but it looks right.  Just change numbers.txt to the name of the file, save the code to a file called sum.py, and in the console type in "python sum.py"

Comment: calling readlines() reads the entire file into memory - using 'for line in file' could be better

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double x = 0, total = 0;
    while (std::cin >> x)
        total += x;
    if (!std::cin.eof())
        return 1;
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

...and the PHP version, just for the sake of completeness

```
cat /file/with/numbers | php -r '$s = 0; while (true) { $e = fgets(STDIN); if (false === $e) break; $s += $e; } echo $s;'
```

Comment: Can be shorter:
seq 1 10 | php -r ' echo array_sum(file("php://stdin")) . PHP_EOL; '

Answer (score 0):

One-liner in Rebol:

```
rebol -q --do 's: 0 while [d: input] [s: s + to-integer d] print s' < infile.txt
```

Unfortunately the above doesn't work in Rebol 3 just yet (**INPUT** doesn't stream STDIN).

So here's an interim solution which also works in Rebol 3:

```
rebol -q --do 's: 0 foreach n to-block read %infile.txt [s: s + n] print s'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using env variable tmp

```
tmp=awk -v tmp="$tmp" '{print $tmp" "$1}' <filename>|echo $tmp|sed "s/ /+/g"|bc

tmp=cat <filename>|awk -v tmp="$tmp" '{print $tmp" "$1}'|echo $tmp|sed "s/ /+/g"|bc
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of `awk` is that, using 1 single stream of integers jotted, it can simultaneously be generating multiple concurrent (and possibly cross-interacting) sequences with barely any code at all :

```
jot - -10 399 | 

mawk2 '__+=($++NF+=__+=-($++NF+=(--$!_)*9^9-1)+($!_^=2))' CONVFMT='%.20g'

121     4261625501                  -4261625380
100     12397455993                 -3874204891
81      28281696469                 -3486784402
64      59662756915                 -3099363913
49      122037457303                -2711943424
36      246399437577                -2324522935
25      494735977625                -1937102446
16      991021637223                -1549681957
9       1983205535923               -1162261468
4       3967185912829               -774840979
1       7934759246149               -387420490
0       15869518492299              -1
1       31738649564111              387420488
4       63476524287249              774840977
9       126951886313041             1162261466
16      253902222944143             1549681955
25      507802508785867             1937102444
36      1015602693048837            2324522933
49      2031202674154301            2711943422
64      4062402248944755            3099363911
81      8124801011105191            3486784400
```

This is a less commonly known feature, but `mawk-1` can directly generate formatted output without using `printf()` or `sprintf()` :

```
 jot - -11111111555359 900729999999999 49987777777556 | 
 
 mawk '$++NF=_+=$!__' CONVFMT='%+\047\043 30.f' OFS='\t' 

-11111111555359           -11,111,111,555,359.
38876666222197            +27,765,554,666,838.
88864443999753           +116,629,998,666,591.
138852221777309          +255,482,220,443,900.

188839999554865          +444,322,219,998,765.
238827777332421          +683,149,997,331,186.
288815555109977          +971,965,552,441,163.

338803332887533        +1,310,768,885,328,696.
388791110665089        +1,699,559,995,993,785.
438778888442645        +2,138,338,884,436,430.
488766666220201        +2,627,105,550,656,631.

538754443997757        +3,165,859,994,654,388.
588742221775313        +3,754,602,216,429,701.
638729999552869        +4,393,332,215,982,570.
688717777330425        +5,082,049,993,312,995.

738705555107981        +5,820,755,548,420,976.
788693332885537        +6,609,448,881,306,513.
838681110663093        +7,448,129,991,969,606.
888668888440649        +8,336,798,880,410,255.
```

With `nawk`, one even more obscure feature is being able to print out the exact `IEEE 754 double precision` floating point hex :

```
 jot - .00001591111137777 \
       9007299999.1111111111 123.990333333328 | 

nawk '$++NF=_+=_+= cos(exp(log($!__)/1.1))' CONVFMT='[ %20.13p ]' OFS='\t' \_=1 

0.00001591111137777     [   0x400fffffffbf27f8 ]
123.99034924443937200   [   0x401f1a2498670bcc ]
247.98068257776736800   [   0x40313bd908775e35 ]
371.97101591109537821   [   0x4040516a505a57a3 ]
495.96134924442338843   [   0x4050b807540a1c3a ]

619.95168257775139864   [   0x4060f800d1abb906 ]
743.94201591107935201   [   0x407112ffc8adec4a ]
867.93234924440730538   [   0x40810bab4a485ad9 ]
991.92268257773525875   [   0x4091089e1149c279 ]

1115.91301591106321212  [   0x40a10ac8cfb09c62 ]
1239.90334924439116548  [   0x40b10a7bfa7fa42d ]
1363.89368257771911885  [   0x40c109c2d1b9947c ]
1487.88401591104707222  [   0x40d10a2644d5ab3b ]
```

`gawk w/ GMP` is even more interesting - they're willing to provide *comma-formatted* **hex** on your behalf, plus strangely padding extra commas in the empty space to its left

=

```
jot -  .000591111137777 90079.1111111111 123.990333333328 | 

gawk -v PREC=20000 -nMbe '
              $++NF  = _ +=(15^16 * log($!__)/log(sqrt(10)))' \
              CONVFMT='< 0x %\04724.12x >' OFS=' | '   \_=1 

# rows skipped in the middle for illustration clarity
 
4339.662257777619743 | < 0x    ,   ,4e6,007,2f4,08a,b93,8b3 >
4463.652591110947469 | < 0x    ,   ,50f,967,27f,e5a,963,518 >
4835.623591110930647 | < 0x    ,   ,58d,250,b65,a8d,45d,b79 >
7315.430257777485167 | < 0x    ,   ,8eb,b36,ee9,fe6,149,da5 >
11779.082257777283303 | < 0x    ,   ,f4b,c34,a75,82a,826,abb >

12151.053257777266481 | < 0x    ,   ,fd7,3c2,25e,1ab,a09,bbf >
16738.695591110394162 | < 0x    ,  1,6b0,f3b,350,ed3,eca,c58 >
17978.598924443671422 | < 0x    ,  1,894,2f2,aba,a30,f63,bae >
20458.405591110225942 | < 0x    ,  1,c64,a40,87e,e35,4d4,896 >
23434.173591110091365 | < 0x    ,  2,108,186,96e,0dc,2ef,d46 >

31741.525924443049007 | < 0x    ,  2,e45,bae,b73,24f,981,637 >
32857.438924442998541 | < 0x    ,  3,014,3a7,b9e,daf,18c,c3e >
33849.361591109620349 | < 0x    ,  3,1b0,9b7,5f1,536,49c,74e >
41536.762257775939361 | < 0x    ,  3,e51,7c1,9b2,e74,516,220 >
45876.423924442409771 | < 0x    ,  4,58c,52d,078,edb,db4,4ba >

53067.863257775417878 | < 0x    ,  5,1aa,cf3,eed,33c,638,456 >
59391.370257775131904 | < 0x    ,  5,c73,38a,54d,b41,98d,a02 >
61127.234924441720068 | < 0x    ,  5,f6d,ce2,c40,117,6d2,6e7 >
66830.790257774875499 | < 0x    ,  6,944,fe1,378,9ea,235,7b0 >
71170.451924441600568 | < 0x    ,  7,0ce,de6,797,df3,009,35d >

76254.055591108335648 | < 0x    ,  7,9b0,f6d,03d,878,edf,97d >
83073.523924441760755 | < 0x    ,  8,5b0,aa9,7f7,a31,89a,f2e >
86669.243591108475812 | < 0x    ,  8,c0d,678,fa3,3b1,aad,f26 >
89149.050257775175851 | < 0x    ,  9,074,278,19d,4c7,443,a00 >
89769.001924441850861 | < 0x    ,  9,18e,464,ff9,0eb,ee4,4e1 >
```

but be weary of syntactical errors -

- this is a selection of what's being printed out to `STDOUT`,
- all `256` byte choices have been observed of what's being printed out, even if it's terminal window

=

```
   jot 3000 | 
   gawk -Me ' _=$++NF=____+=$++NF=___-= $++NF=__+=$++NF=\
             _^= exp(cos($++NF=______+=($1) %10 + 1))'   \
                                  ____=-111111089 OFMT='%32c`' 


 char >>[  --[ U+ 2 | 2 (ASCII) freq >>[ 8 sumtotal >>[ 45151 
 char >>[  --[ U+ 4 | 4 (ASCII) freq >>[ 11 sumtotal >>[ 45166 
 char >>[  --[ U+ 14 | 20 (ASCII) freq >>[ 9 sumtotal >>[ 45301 
 char >>[ + --[ U+ 2B | 43 (ASCII) freq >>[ 9 sumtotal >>[ 60645 
 char >>[ --[ U+ 9 | 9 (ASCII) freq >>[ 12 sumtotal >>[ 45216 
 char >>[ 8 --[ U+ 38 | 56 (ASCII) freq >>[ 1682 sumtotal >>[ 82522 
 char >>[ Q --[ U+ 51 | 81 (ASCII) freq >>[ 6 sumtotal >>[ 85040 
 char >>[ Y --[ U+ 59 | 89 (ASCII) freq >>[ 8 sumtotal >>[ 85105 
 char >>[ g --[ U+ 67 | 103 (ASCII) freq >>[ 10 sumtotal >>[ 85212 
 char >>[ p --[ U+ 70 | 112 (ASCII) freq >>[ 7 sumtotal >>[ 85411 
 char >>[ v --[ U+ 76 | 118 (ASCII) freq >>[ 7 sumtotal >>[ 85462 
 char >>[ ? --[ \216 \x8E | 142 (8-bit byte) freq >>[ 15 sumtotal >>[ 85653 
 char >>[ ? --[ \222 \x92 | 146 (8-bit byte) freq >>[ 13 sumtotal >>[ 85698 
 char >>[ ? --[ \250 \xA8 | 168 (8-bit byte) freq >>[ 9 sumtotal >>[ 85967 
 char >>[ ? --[ \307 \xC7 | 199 (8-bit byte) freq >>[ 7 sumtotal >>[ 86345 
 char >>[ ? --[ \332 \xDA | 218 (8-bit byte) freq >>[ 69 sumtotal >>[ 86576 
 char >>[ ? --[ \352 \xEA | 234 (8-bit byte) freq >>[ 6 sumtotal >>[ 86702 
 char >>[ ? --[ \354 \xEC | 236 (8-bit byte) freq >>[ 5 sumtotal >>[ 86713 
 char >>[ ? --[ \372 \xFA | 250 (8-bit byte) freq >>[ 11 sumtotal >>[ 86823 
 char >>[ ? --[ \376 \xFE | 254 (8-bit byte) freq >>[ 9 sumtotal >>[ 86859
```

Answer (score 0):

[Miller tool(s)](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/10min/) are definitely an overkill for this task, but 1) let's have them here for completeness' sake; 2) they might come in handy for further processing:

```
 % seq 10 | mlr stats1 -a sum -f 1
1_sum=55
```

Answer (score 0):

if the numbers that require summing up happen to fall within a contiguous range, you can use the old trick involving

```
   f(n) := n x ( n + 1 ) / 2
```

and doing

```
  f( high-side ) - \
  f(  low-side  - 1 )
```

as fast as `awk` is, a direct computation is still muuuuch faster than summation :

*caveat being : without any big-int library, this approach is constrianed by 64-bit fp precision*:

```
    ( time ( jot - 19495729 21895729 | pvE0 |

    mawk2 '{ __+=$_ } END { print __ }' )) 
    
    sleep 0.5

   ( time ( echo '19495729 21895729' | pvE0 |
```

---

```
    mawk2 '
    function __(___, _) {
         return \
         _ * ((_ + (_^=_<_)) * (\
             _/= _+_)) - ___ * _ * --___ 
    }
    BEGIN {
        CONVFMT = "%.250g"
        OFS = ORS } ($!NF = __($1, $2))^_'  ))
```

---

```
      in0: 20.6MiB 0:00:00 [49.4MiB/s] [49.4MiB/s] [ <=>]
  ( jot - 19495729 21895729 | pvE 0.1 in0 | mawk2 '{ __+=$_ } END { print __ }')

     0.59s user 0.03s system 141% cpu 0.440 total
     1  49669770295729 0x2D2CA503B9B1


      in0: 18.0 B 0:00:00 [ 462KiB/s] [ 462KiB/s] [<=>]
  ( echo '19495729 21895729' | pvE 0.1 in0 | mawk2 ; )

     0.00s user 0.01s system 62% cpu 0.024 total
     1  49669770295729 0x2D2CA503B9B1
```

** the code saved the `/ 2` from high-side so low-side could be performed as `* 0.5`

Answer (score -1):

Simple php

```
  cat numbers.txt | php -r "echo array_sum(explode(PHP_EOL, stream_get_contents(STDIN)));"
```

Answer (score -6):

Ok, here is how to do it in PowerShell (PowerShell core, should work on Windows, Linux and Mac)

```
Get-Content aaa.dat | Measure-Object -Sum
```

Comment: This question is tagged [[shell]]: "Without a specific tag, a portable (POSIX-compliant) solution should be assumed" not PowerShell