# How to get grand total filesize of all files matching a filename pattern in the shell?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to calculate the total size in bytes of all files (in a directory tree) matching a filename pattern just using the shell. This is what I have so far:

> find -name *.undo -exec stat -c%s {} \; | awk '{total += $1} END {print total}'

Is there an easier way to do this? I feel like there should be a simple du or find switch that does this for me but I can't find one.

To be clear I want to total files matching a pattern anywhere under a directory tree which means

> du -bs *.undo

won't work because it only matches the files in the current directory.

Comment: Anyway, `du` (or `ls`) won't work above a few thousands of files (" Argument list too long" error).

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try:

```
find . -name "*.undo" -ls | awk '{total += $7} END {print total}'
```

On my system the size of the file is the seventh field in the `find -ls` output. If your `find … -ls` output is different, adjust.

In this version, using the existing directory information (file size) and the built-in ls feature of find should be efficient, avoiding process creations or file i/o.

Comment: That should work, but the -ls option to find, and awk, are overkill for this task.

Comment: I would add "-type f" to the find command to prevent from incorrect total if there are directories matching "*.undo" glob.

Comment: Note that if you need several patterns to match, you will have to use escaped parenthesis for the whole expression to match otherwise the `-ls` will apply only to the last pattern. For instance, if you want to match all jpeg and png files (trusting filenames), you would use `find . \( -iname "*.jpg" -o -iname "*.jpeg" -o -iname "*.png" \) -ls | awk '{total += $7} END {print total}'` (`-iname` is for case insensitive search ; also, note the space between the expression and the escaped parenthesis).

Comment: Is this _really_ the easiest way to do `dir *.undo /s` in Linux?

Answer (score 36):

With zsh, you can use extended globbing to do:

du -c **/*.undo

Answer (score 22):

```
find -name *.undo -print0 | du -hc --files0-from=-
```

Comment: This lists all files. Is there a way to show just the total? Regardless, I'm thinking this is a 'correct answer' candidate.

Comment: I like this because it shows the size 'human readable'.
@Tyler Collier to show only total use tail:


`find -type f -name '*.undo' -print0 | du -hc --files0-from=- | tail -n 1`

Comment: This is the best answer I have ever seen for doing this on linux... its also executes about a 1,000 times faster than any other answer I have seen, since du on a file executes so fast, plus it gives output in human readable terms

Comment: `-files0-from` doesn't work if you have too many files, I got an error about too long file name from it

Answer (score 18):

```
du -c *pattern*
```

This will print the total on the last line of output.

Comment: And use tail to trim off all but the last line.  +1.  =]

Comment: That'll only find the files that match the pattern in the current directory, though - won't it?

Comment: You can use a pattern like `*/*.undo`... although that would only find files with the undo extension that are one folder deep... also wouldn't find any in the current directory.

Comment: Simplest solution so far !

Comment: `du -ch *pattern*` to get the results in human readable format (e.g., 99K 42M 67.8G)

Answer (score 9):

I have been looking at this problem too (only a year later...) - only just found this page.

Something that I found works (for me) is the following:

```
find /mnt/iso -name *.avi -printf "%s\n" | paste -sd+ - | bc
```

This will return the total size of all the .avi files in all the sub-folders below /mnt/iso

I have to give credit to radoulov for the paste command - see this page:
[Shell command to sum integers, one per line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450799/linux-command-to-sum-integers-one-per-line)

Just to add - just in case a folder matches the search term - it's a good idea to use `-type f` in the find command too.

Answer (score 8):

```
find -name '*.undo' -exec wc -c {} + | tail -n 1
```

should give the actual total number of bytes in the files, if you don't have too many files (where "too many" is going to be a really large number, probably in the thousands).  Or if you just want to get the number alone,

```
find -name '*.undo' -exec wc -c {} + | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f 1
```

Comment: You should quote '*.undo', "*.undo", \*.undo, or similar; otherwise, you'll get wrong results if there exists a.undo file in the current directory.

Answer (score 5):

Python is part of most linux distributions.

```
import os
import fnmatch
size= 0
for path, dirs, files in os.walk( '.' ):
    for f in files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(f,'*.py'):
            fileSize= os.path.getsize( os.path.join(path,f) ) 
            print f, fileSize
            size += fileSize
print size
```

Longish, but perfectly clear and highly extensible.

Answer (score 3):

```
find -name '*.undo' -print0 | du -hc --files0-from=- | tail -n 1
```

Put together from [gerdemb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27478/gerdemb)'s and strager's contributions. Using `du -cb` should display bytes.

Answer (score 2):

I use du command like this to get the number only:

```
du file_list | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this simple one.

```
find ./ -name *.undo | xargs wc
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can just do this:

```
dir=$1

for file in $dir/* ; do

 length_file=`stat -c %s $file`
 echo "File $file has length $length_file"
 length_total=`expr $length_total + $length_file`

done

echo "Total length: $length_total ."
```

Where stat displays a file or file system status. The argument -c means using the specified format instead of the default one, and the format sequence $s allows the display of the total size of bytes.

```
expr
```

Just evaluates an expression.

Answer (score 0):

Perl one-liner:

```
find . -name "*.undo" -ls | perl -lane '$t += $F[6]; END{print $t}'
```

The `@F` autosplit array starts at index `$F[0]` while awk fields start with $1, hence `$F[6]` is used instead of awk's `$7`

Answer (score 0):

du -c  | awk '/./{line=$0} END{print $1}'

Answer (score 0):

I think the version with xargs could be imroved (simplified)
ls -1 *.undo | xargs wc

Answer (score -3):

Check the [du](http://linux.die.net/man/1/du) (disk usage) command.