# Syntax To Get Total File Size

Tags: bash, fedora, 7zip

So I'm trying to zip up a large number of files, but I want to see the total size of the files before I start zipping.

Before executing the following command to archive the files:

```
7za a files.7z files_2014-11-03*
```

I need to make sure I'm not zipping up too many files at once.

I used this command to find what I needed:

```
find -type f -name 'files_2014-11-03*' | wc -l
```

Is there something else I can pipe this to to get my wanted results?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate size of files in shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599027/calculate-size-of-files-in-shell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
du -hc files_2014-11-03* | tail -1
```

I would use `-c` instead of `-s`

```
-c, --total           produce a grand total
```

Comment: This gives an innacurate size total.

Comment: If you want accurate size, then don't use `-h`

Comment: I mean steven Penny's command produces 127 GB and this one produces 3.7 GB. Which is correct?

Comment: Penny's answer is counting all the files in that directory, mine is specific for `files_2014-11-03*`

Answer (score 1):

```
du -bhs
```

More info

```
-b, --bytes
       equivalent to `--apparent-size --block-size=1'

-h, --human-readable
       print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)

-s, --summarize
       display only a total for each argument
```

[explainshell.com](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=du+-bhs)