# Determine Java code size of modules

Tags: java

For a normal executable file on Linux I would do something like `size <executable>` to get a quick overview, or `readelf -a <executable>` for a more detailed overview.

Is there a similar quick-and-dirty way of dumping a `JAR` file and a `CLASS` file?

**EDIT**: Just to explain my requirement a bit better, `javap` does report a disassembly of the code, but it doesn't display an at-a-glance summary like `size` and `readelf` above. I am trying out an alternative design for an application, and want to know if my changes are really improving or degrading memory sizes. I know I could run all the code in a profiling tool, but for now I just want a static measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the `jcf-dump` command, and with a bit of experimenting and help from other StackOverflow answers, I came up with this:

```
jcf-dump -v <class_name> | grep -Po 'code_length:(\K\d+)' | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }'
```

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5081519/1270789) for the `grep`, and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2702577/1270789) for the `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

For a start, try out the `javap` command and its various options and see if that gives you the information that you need.

Comment: Thanks, that works to some extent, but there's no happy medium between  `javap` and `javap -verbose`, unfortunately.