# Bash command to sum a column of numbers

Tags: bash

I want a bash command that I can pipe into that will sum a column of numbers. I just want a quick one liner that will do something essentially like this:

```
cat FileWithColumnOfNumbers.txt | sum
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3934423/376454

Comment: FYI the `awk` solution is both [easier to remember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450799/shell-command-to-sum-integers-one-per-line#comment12469220_451204) and about 2x faster (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3098072/52074) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450799/shell-command-to-sum-integers-one-per-line#comment20238060_451204)).

Answer (score 1109, accepted):

## Using existing file:

```
paste -sd+ infile | bc
```

## Using stdin:

```
<cmd> | paste -sd+ | bc
```

Edit:
With some *paste* implementations you need to be more explicit when reading from *stdin*:

`<cmd> | paste -sd+ - | bc`

**Options used**:

> -s (serial) - merges all the lines into a single line
>
> -d          - use a non-default delimiter (the character `+` in this case)

Comment: Just as an FYI, the `-s` option is in GNU `paste`; it is not supported by Mac OS X 10.7.4 `paste`.  However, since the POSIX 2008 specification of [`paste`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html) supports `-s`, this is a deficiency in the Mac OS X version.

Comment: Just another FYI for OS X, I had to add a - at the end of the paste command in order for this to work on OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: With `bc -l` you can even add up float numbers. With `cut` you can select columns from the input: `cat input.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 8 | paste -sd+ | bc -l` will add all float numbers in column 8 of the input (space being the field separator).

Comment: Well, that would be easier with awk: `awk 'END { print s } { s += $8 }' infile` :)

Comment: <code>bc</code> doesn't seem to support scientific notation. I have decimal numbers some of which are like <code>2.345e-3</code>. Thoughts? Perl/Python?

Comment: @Ben, in the thread below you'll find _awk_ and _Perl_ solutions.

Comment: Sorry, all you paste lovers. -1 from me for being too specific. This works ONLY if you have nothing but numbers in your file. I almost have never had that situation. Google "bash add column numbers" and you get here. Invariably, I am trying to add a column interspersed with other data (du output or the like- we are talking bash, the sysadmin's language, right?). Ghostdog's awk answer works with any data that includes a column of numbers AND other columns. It's much less fragile, almost as concise, and faster to boot.

Comment: Had to add float numbers `bc -l` gave parse error. Using `octave` instead of `bc` worked nicely.

Comment: @AxelBregnsbo, it must be a decimal separator issue (, vs. .), because obviously bc supports floating point calculations.

Comment: paste and bc don't come out of the box, while awk does, so I prefer awk.

Comment: `<cmd> | paste -sd+ - | bc ` was like a magic to me. bash command line rocks!

Comment: This only works if there is exactly one column in the file.

Comment: I didn't know about the paste command. Nice trick :)

Comment: this has lots of upvotes but can the answer include what all the commands and switches are actually doing?

Comment: I agree with @red888's comment; the answer could really benefit from that. Additionally, I see the `d` option being used in `-sd+` but I don't see a character being given as a delimeter? How does that work?

Comment: On mac os I had to do: `command | paste -s -d'+' - | bc` instead

Answer (score 247):

I like the chosen answer. However, it tends to be slower than awk since 2 tools are needed to do the job.

```
$ wc -l file
49999998 file

$ time paste -sd+ file | bc
1448700364

real    1m36.960s
user    1m24.515s
sys     0m1.772s

$ time awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}' file
1448700364

real    0m45.476s
user    0m40.756s
sys     0m0.287s
```

Comment: Good point! On SunOS 5.8 bc even core dumps with such a big input file (see my post below).

Comment: awk is the correct tool for the job! The bc solution is OK but what happens when you need to sum two columns or perhaps filter out negative numbers. With awk you can easily and sensibly add in extra logic, with the bc solution you end up with piping through yet another command (cut or grep)

Comment: I would use awk also because it allows to initialize `s` to 0, by doing `awk 'BEGIN{s=0}{s+=$1}END{print s}'`.  In this case, if an empty column is piped into `paste | bc`, the latter pipe will return `0` instead of null. (There may be cases where and empty column is a legitimate input).

Comment: This solution seems to round down though to a single decimal? I have a list of numbers which happen to be to 2 decimal places (dollar/cents). With the paste/bc I get 11027.24, but with the awk solution I get 11027.2. That's a pretty critical bug if you end up using this one-liner with monetary values!

Comment: @romemmy Never fear, awk can do precision: `awk '{s+=$1}END{printf "%.2f\n",s}' /tmp/py.venv.strace`  . I'll update the answer.

Comment: `awk` handles empty lines `paste -sd+ -` do not

Answer (score 100):

The following command will add all the lines(first field of the awk output)

```
awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}' filename
```

Comment: This ones works with mac OS 10.15

Comment: `command | paste -s -d'+' - | bc` that one works on mac OS too

Comment: On my system (Ubuntu 20.04) the command with  nawk is about twice faster than  with gawk (default awk),  and about x3 faster than the winner `paste|bc`  command..  Tested with the `1..49999998` file.

Answer (score 75):

Does two lines count?

```
awk '{ sum += $1; }
     END { print sum; }' "$@"
```

You can then use it without the superfluous 'cat':

```
sum < FileWithColumnOfNumbers.txt
sum   FileWithColumnOfNumbers.txt
```

FWIW: on MacOS X, you can do it with a one-liner:

```
awk '{ sum += $1; } END { print sum; }' "$@"
```

Comment: @jskaggz - see my answer for a bit shorter/simpler Perl version :)

Comment: the one-liner awk works on any awk that I've tried, not just OS X

Comment: @unhammer: I don't have access to 7th Edition UNIX and its version of `awk` any more.  I don't know whether the one-line would have worked there, but I didn't try it back then when I learned `awk`.  You're probably right; all current versions of `awk` are likely to support the one-liner.

Comment: what does the $@ do? It seems to have no effect for my usage of pbpaste | awk ...

Comment: @DavidMann: `"$@"` is used inside a script to represent all the arguments to the script, or nothing/none if there were no arguments.  If you're using the `awk` in `pbpaste | awk …`, you simply omit the `"$@"` (though it would usually do no damage; most interactive shells at a terminal have no 'positional parameters' so `"$@"` is nothing).  But if you have a shell script `sumcol1.sh`, adding the `"$@"` would be sensible — you'd then use `pbpaste | sumcol1.sh` or similar and it would work correctly, and so would `sumcol1.sh file1 file2`.

Answer (score 21):

[a followup to ghostdog74s comments]

```
bash-2.03$ uname -sr
SunOS 5.8

bash-2.03$ perl -le 'print for 1..49999998' > infile

bash-2.03$ wc -l infile
 49999998 infile

bash-2.03$  time paste -sd+ infile | bc
bundling space exceeded on line 1, teletype
Broken Pipe

real    0m0.062s
user    0m0.010s
sys     0m0.010s

bash-2.03$ time nawk '{s+=$1}END{print s}' infile
1249999925000001

real    2m0.042s
user    1m59.220s
sys     0m0.590s
bash-2.03$ time /usr/xpg4/bin/awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}' infile
1249999925000001

real    2m27.260s
user    2m26.230s
sys     0m0.660s

bash-2.03$ time perl -nle'
  $s += $_; END { print $s }
   ' infile
1.249999925e+15

real    1m34.663s
user    1m33.710s
sys     0m0.650s
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the coredump in the bc version of this.  I'm hesitant to change the "answer" of this question because the bc version works fine for me (i'm totalling up 30 numbers).

Comment: +1 for the perl version - fastest on my ubuntu 12.04

Comment: +1 for Perl version working on floating-point numbers. Also, for exactly what I was looking for, here's summing a particular column (column 2 indexed from zero): `perl -nle '$s += (split)[2]; END { print $s }' foo.txt` or using pipes: `cat foo.txt | perl -nle '$s += (split)[2]; END { print $s }'`.

Comment: Also: `paste -sd+ -|perl -nle 'print eval'`

Answer (score 15):

You can use bc (calculator). Assuming your file with #s is called "n":

```
$ cat n
1
2
3
$ (cat n | tr "\012" "+" ; echo "0") | bc 
6
```

The `tr` changes all newlines to "+"; then we append 0 after the last plus, then we pipe the expression (`1+2+3+0`) to the calculator

Or, if you are OK with using awk or perl, here's a Perl one-liner:

```
$perl -nle '$sum += $_ } END { print $sum' n
6
```

Comment: For the perl, this works too: `perl -nle '$s+=$_}{print $s'` It is a bit simpler. :)

Answer (score 11):

```
while read -r num; do ((sum += num)); done < inputfile; echo $sum
```

Comment: If you've a lot of numbers to add, this ain't so good: using @radulov's file, this took 10m28s (Ubuntu 12.04). The perl solution took 11s, awk 13s and |bc 37s.

Comment: @drevicko On the other hand, if there is not a lot of numbers to add (jskaggz tell his need is for 30 numbers), this way is the quickest, because there is no fork!

Comment: @techno True enough, though there's only one fork. On the other hand, for 30 numbers, speed is a bit irrelevant - best to go with the tool you're most familiar with, such as bash (:

Comment: He-he, this is in fact the first answer to question asked ("how to sum column with **bash**").

Answer (score 5):

Use a `for` loop to iterate over your file …

```
sum=0; for x in `cat <your-file>`; do let sum+=x; done; echo $sum
```

Comment: without `cat` :: `for s in $(< infile); do let sum+=$s ; done && echo $sum`

Comment: This will not work for float numbers

Answer (score 4):

If you have ruby installed

```
cat FileWithColumnOfNumbers.txt | xargs ruby -e "puts ARGV.map(&:to_i).inject(&:+)"
```