# Awk conditional sum from a CSV file

Tags: csv, awk

I have a CSV file from which I would like to extract some pieces of information: for each distinct value in one colum, I would like to compute the sum of the corresponding values in another column. Eventually, I may do it in Python, but I believe there could be a simple solution using `awk`.

This could be the CSV file:

```
2    1:2010-1-bla:bla    1.6
2    2:2010-1-bla:bla   1.1
2    2:2010-1-bla:bla    3.4
2    3:2010-1-bla:bla    -1.3
2    3:2010-1-bla:bla    6.0
2    3:2010-1-bla:bla    1.1
2    4:2010-1-bla:bla    -1.0
2    5:2010-1-bla:bla    10.9
```

I would like to get:

```
1    1.6
2    4.5
3    5.8
4    -1.0
5    10.9
```

---

For now, I can only extract:

**a) the values of the first colum:**

```
awk -F ' ' '{print $(2)}' MyFile.csv | awk -F ':' '{print $(1)}'
```

and then get:

```
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
5
```

**b) and the values equal to, say, `1.1` in the last column with:**

`awk -F '    ' '{print $(NF)}' MyFile.csv | awk '$1 == 1.1'`

and then get:

```
1.1
1.1
```

I am not able to simultaneously extract the columns I am interested in, which may help me in the end. Here is a sample output which may ease the computation of the sums (I don't know):

```
1    1.6
2    1.1
2    3.4
3    -1.3
3    6.0
3    1.1
4    -1.0
5    10.9
```

Edit: Thanks to Elenaher, we could say the input is the file above.

Comment: can you give us example input?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$ awk -F"[: \t]+" '{a[$2]+=$NF}END{for(i in a ) print i,a[i] }' file
4 -1
5 10.9
1 1.6
2 4.5
3 5.8
```

Comment: I have finally decided to accept this answer since it is really more general and could adapt to a lot of similar problems by tweaking the separators or the number of the columns.

Answer (score 4):

This is assuming you have the two columns you showed before: 1 1.1

```
BEGIN {
    last = "";
    sum = 0;
}

{
    if ($1 != last) {
        if (last != "") {
            print last " " sum;
        }
        sum = 0;
        last = $1;
    }
    sum = sum + $2
}

END {
    print last " " sum;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is great to answer my second question. I wish I could upvote it more than once.

Answer (score 2):

So, assuming that your input looks like this:

```
unique_col, to_sum
1.3, 1 2 3
1.3, 5 6 7
1.4, 2 3 4
```

Then this should do the trick:

```
$ awk -F, '{ if (seen[$1] == "") { split($2, to_sum, " "); seen[$1] = 0; for (x in to_sum) seen[$1] += to_sum[x]; }} END { for (x in seen) { if (x != "") { print x " " seen[x]; }}}' < input
1.3 6
1.4 9
```

Comment: It works great on your input, but mine is a bit different. Still thanks.

Comment: Ah, sorry — wrote it before you had the example up, so I had to guess =\

Answer (score 1):

For your last question, you can use `split` and display simultaneously the two columns :

```
cat filename | awk '{split($2,tab,":"); id = tab[1]; print id " -> " $3;}'
```

That prints :

```
1 -> 1.6
2 -> 1.1
2 -> 3.4
3 -> -1.3
3 -> 6.0
3 -> 1.1
4 -> -1.0
5 -> 10.9
```

For the complete result you can use :

```
awk -F, '{ split($1,line,"    "); split(line[2],tab,":"); id=tab[1]; if (sums[id]=="") {sums[id] = 0;} sums[id]+=line[3];} END {for (i=1;i<=length(sums);i++) print i " -> "sums[i]}' < test
```

that prints :

```
1 -> 1.6
2 -> 4.5
3 -> 5.8
4 -> -1
5 -> 10.9
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not know the `split` keyword for `awk`.

Comment: Thanks, your code works (although I have to edit the input since there was a missing space which is not handled then).

Answer (score 1):

If Perl is an option:

`perl -F'(\s+|:)' -lane '$h{$F[2]} += $F[-1]; END{print "$_ $h{$_}" for sort keys %h}' file`

output:

```
1 1.6
2 4.5
3 5.8
4 -1
5 10.9
```

These command-line options are used:

- `-n` loop around every line of the input file
- `-l` removes newlines before processing, and adds them back in afterwards
- `-a` autosplit mode – split input lines into the `@F` array.  Defaults to splitting on whitespace.
- `-e` execute the perl code
- `-F` autosplit modifier, in this case splits on a color or one-or-more whitespace

`@F` is the array of words in each line, indexed starting with `$F[0]`
`$F[-1]` is the last word
Store result in hash `%h`
At the END, iterate through the sorted keys of the hash
Print each element `$_` and the hash value `$h{$_}`

Answer (score 0):

```
{ 
  b=$2;               # assign column 2 to the variable 'b'
  sub( /:.*/, "", b); # get rid of everything after the first colon in b
  results[b] += $3     
}
END {  for (result in results )print result " " results[result] }
```

Comment: I get the following message: `syntax error near unexpected token `/:.*/,'`