# Manipulating data text file with bash command?

Tags: bash

I was given this text file, call stock.txt, the content of the text file is:

```
pepsi;drinks;3
fries;snacks;6
apple;fruits;9
baron;drinks;7
orange;fruits;2
chips;snacks;8
```

I will need to use bash-script to come up this output:

```
Total amount for drinks: 10
Total amount for snacks: 14
Total amount for fruits: 11
Total of everything: 35
```

My gut tells me I will need to use sed, group, grep and something else.
Where should I start?

Comment: Thanks for being honest. Yeah, it's tempting to just get the direct solution, but you'll be screwed come exam time if we just do it for you. But people here are happy to give you some ideas.

Comment: Hi Rafe, thats what I am worried.. Exam.. hhaha.. Thus I need to be honest, and find the solution by myself, but I need your guidelines, the course notes I have are very limited, lack of the examples.

Comment: Are there restrictions on what tools you're allowed to use? awk could do this quite easily...

Comment: Hi David, no restrictions, but please use the easy one first, as I dont want to show my lecturer how good my code is, instead, I want to learn how to use first. I think I forgot to mention awk.

Comment: This does indeed scream awk, but then it's (almost) not bash :)  stick with sed, split your line, and use expr to do your accumulating.

Comment: Why group? Am I missing something? (by the way I will start with grep)

Comment: What version of bash are you using? Is it 4.x or 3.x?

Comment: Hi Sorpigal, this is the result when i type uname -a. "Linux ubuntu 2.6.32-25-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 17 20:26:08 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux"

Comment: To show your Bash version, try: `echo $BASH_VERSION`.

Comment: Take a look at the `case` statement. It can be used in place of a sequence of `if` statements. You can do `while IFS=; read -r ...` and, in cases like this, you won't need to save and restore the value of `IFS`. You should almost always use `-r` with `read` to preserve backslashes. You should usually put variables inside quotes when you output their values, for example: `done < "$INPUT"` and `echo -e "Drinks: $DRINKS"`.

Comment: I have removed the answer from this question and posted it as wiki below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would break the exercise down into steps

Step 1: Read the file one line at a time

```
while read -r line
do
    # do something with $line
done
```

Step 2: Pattern match (drinks, snacks, fruits) and do some simple arithmetic. This step requires that you tokenized each line which I'll leave an exercise for you to figure out.

```
if [[ "$line" =~ "drinks" ]]
then
    echo "matched drinks"
    .
    .
    .
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Amir, I use the while and if statement like you mentioned, and it works now. But I am more curious of how to use sed/grep/awk to achieve this. Any guides for me?

Answer (score 1):

Pure Bash. A nice application for an associative array:

```
declare -A category                  # associative array
IFS=';'
while read name cate price ; do
  ((category[$cate]+=price))
done < stock.txt

sum=0
for cate in ${!category[@]}; do       # loop over the indices
  printf "Total amount of %s: %d\n" $cate ${category[$cate]}
  ((sum+=${category[$cate]}))
done

printf "Total amount of everything: %d\n" $sum
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a short description here about processing comma separated files in bash here:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bash-read-comma-separated-cvsfile/

You could do something similar. Just change `IFS` from comma to semicolon.

Oh yeah, and a general hint for learning bash: `man` is your friend. Use this command to see manual pages for all (or most) of commands and utilities.

Example: `man read` shows the manual page for read command. On most systems it will be opened in `less`, so you should exit the manual by pressing q (may be funny, but it took me a while to figure that out)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am reading it =) But the awk very tempting.. it looks like very easy to solve my question. http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-awk.html#DATA. BUt as, KeinDTimm said, I should use sed/grep first.. Anyway, I will explore 1 by 1

Comment: awk is indeed way cooler than this. Well, the best advice I could give you is: do both :D

Comment: Hi Goran, I manage to do it but using while and simple if statements. I am still havent touch the sed/grep and.... the AWK.. any hint on using that three commands?

Comment: Excellent. You have some good pointers for awk in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934423/awk-conditional-sum-from-a-csv-file ...and of course, the `man awk`

Comment: `help` is also your friend for bash builtins such as `declare`, `set` and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this is using a hash table, which is supported directly by bash 4.x and of course can be found in awk and perl. If you don't have a hash table then you need to loop twice: once to collect the unique values of the second column, once to total.

There are many ways to do this. Here's a fun one which doesn't use awk, sed or perl. The only external utilities I've used here are cut, sort and uniq. You could even replace `cut` with a little more effort. In fact lines 5-9 could have been written more easily with grep, (`grep $kind stock.txt`) but I avoided that to show off the power of bash.

```
for kind in $(cut -d\; -f 2 stock.txt | sort | uniq) ; do
    total=0
    while read d ; do
        total=$(( total+d ))
    done < <(
        while read line ; do 
            [[ $line =~ $kind ]] && echo $line
        done < stock.txt | cut -d\; -f3
    )

    echo "Total amount for $kind: $total" 
done
```

We lose the strict ordering of your original output here. An exercise for you might be to find a way not to do that.

Discussion:
The first line describes a sub-shell with a simple pipeline using `cut`. We read the third field from the `stock.txt` file, with fields delineated by `;`, written `\;` here so the shell does not interpret it. The result is a newline-separated list of values from `stock.txt`. This is piped to `sort`, then `uniq`. This performs our "grouping" step, since the pipeline will output an alphabetic list of items from the second column but will only list each item once no matter how many times it appeared in the input file.

Also on the first line is a typical `for` loop: For each item resulting from the sub-shell we loop once, storing the value of the item in the variable `kind`. This is the other half of the grouping step, making sure that each "Total" output line occurs once.

On the second line `total` is initialized to zero so that it always resets whenever a new group is started.

The third line begins the 'totaling' loop, in which for the current `kind` we find the sum of its occurrences. here we declare that we will read the variable `d` in from stdin on each iteration of the loop.

On the fourth line the totaling actually occurs: Using [shell arithmatic](http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/arithmetic_expressions.shtml) we add the value in `d` to the value in `total`.

Line five ends the while loop and then describes its input. We use shell input redirection via `<` to specify that the input to the loop, and thus to the `read` command, comes from a file. We then use [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) to specify that the file will actually be the results of a command.

On the sixth line the command that will feed the while-read loop begins. It is itself another while-read loop, this time reading into the variable `line`. On the seventh line the test is performed via a [conditional construct](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs). Here we use `[[` for its `=~` operator, which is a pattern matching operator. We are testing to see whether `$line` matches our current `$kind`.

On the eighth line we end the inner while-read loop and specify that its input comes from the `stock.txt` file, then we pipe the output of the entire loop, which by now is simply all lines matching `$kind`, to `cut` and instruct it to show only the third field, which is the numeric field. On line nine we then end the process substitution command, the output of which is a newline-delineated list of numbers from lines which were of the group specified by `kind`.

Given that the total is now known and the kind is known it is a simple matter to print the results to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

*The below answer is OP's. As it was edited in the question itself and OP hasn't come back for 6 years, I am editing out the answer from the question and posting it as wiki here.*

---

My answer, to get the total price, I use this:

```
...
PRICE=0
IFS=";"     # new field separator, the end of line   
while read name cate price
do
let PRICE=PRICE+$price
done < stock.txt
echo $PRICE
```

When I echo, its :35, which is correct. Now I will moving on using awk to get the sub-category result.

Whole Solution:

Thanks guys, I manage to do it myself. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=stock.txt
PRICE=0
DRINKS=0
SNACKS=0
FRUITS=0
old_IFS=$IFS      # save the field separator   
IFS=";"     # new field separator, the end of line   
while read name cate price
do
    if [ $cate = "drinks" ]; then   
        let DRINKS=DRINKS+$price
fi

if [ $cate = "snacks" ]; then
        let SNACKS=SNACKS+$price
fi

if [ $cate = "fruits" ]; then
        let FRUITS=FRUITS+$price
fi

# Total
let PRICE=PRICE+$price
done < $INPUT

echo -e "Drinks: " $DRINKS
echo -e "Snacks: " $SNACKS
echo -e "Fruits: " $FRUITS
echo -e "Price " $PRICE 
IFS=$old_IFS
```