# Adding (mathematically) columns of a CSV based on information in another column with PowerShell

Tags: math, powershell, csv, addition

I was having a really hard time describing what I need in the Title, so I apologize ahead of time if that makes absolutely no sense.

If I have a CSV that has 2 columns, one with a persons name and a second column with a numeric value I need to find the duplicates in the names column then add the numeric values for that person together to get a total number in a new CSV.

This is a very simplified version of the real CSV

```
Name,Number
Dog,1
Cat,2
Fish,1
Dog,3
Dog,2
Cat,2
Fish,1
```

Given the information above, what I would like to be able to produce is this:

```
Name,Number
Dog,6
Cat,4
Fish,2
```

I really don't have any idea how to get there or if it's possible with PowerShell. I can only get as far as using group-object to group by name, but I have no clue how to add the columns after that.

The biggest problem I'm coming across with my research on this is that most if not all the results I get when googling involve adding new columns to a csv and not performing the mathematical calculation.

Comment: I would call what you are describing as 'aggregating'. You can see a bash/awk answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934423/awk-conditional-sum-from-a-csv-file

Answer (score 5):

I finally got it

```
$csvfile = import-csv c:\csvfile.csv

$csvfile | group name | select name,@{Name="Totals";Expression={($_.group | Measure-Object -sum number).sum}}
```

Credit goes to:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ParsingCSVsAndPoorMansWebLogAnalysisWithPowerShell.aspx