# how to sum each column in a file using bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file on the following format

```
id_1,1,0,2,3,lable1
id_2,3,2,2,1,lable1
id_3,5,1,7,6,lable1
```

and I want the summation of each column ( I have over 300 columns)

```
9,3,11,10,lable1
```

how can I do that using bash. 
I tried using what described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096259/bash-command-to-sum-a-column-of-numbers) but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the totals would need to be grouped by the label in the last column, you could try this:

```
awk -F, '
  {
    L[$NF]
    for(i=2; i<NF; i++) T[$NF,i]+=$i
  }
  END{
    for(i in L){
      s=i
      for(j=NF-1; j>1; j--) s=T[i,j] FS s
      print s
    }
  }
' file
```

If the labels in the last column are sorted then you could try without arrays and save memory:

```
awk -F, '
  function labelsum(){
    s=p
    for(i=NF-1; i>1; i--) s=T[i] FS s
    print s
    split(x,T)
  }
  p!=$NF{
    if(p) labelsum()
    p=$NF
  }
  {
    for(i=2; i<NF; i++) T[i]+=$i
  }
  END {
    labelsum()
  }
' file
```

Comment: Thank you your solution added the advantage for using more than one label in the file

Answer (score 6):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F, '{for (i=2;i<NF;i++)a[i]+=$i}END{for (i=2;i<NF;i++) printf a[i]",";print $NF}' file
9,3,11,10,lable1
```

This will print the sum of each column *(from i=2 .. i=n-1)* in a comma separated file followed the value of the last column from the last row *(i.e. lable1)*.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Perl one-liner:

```
<file perl -lanF, -E 'for ( 0 .. $#F ) { $sums{ $_ } += $F[ $_ ]; } END { say join ",", map { $sums{ $_ } } sort keys %sums; }'
```

It will only do sums, so the first and last column in your example will be 0.

This version will follow your example output:

```
<file perl -lanF, -E 'for ( 1 .. $#F - 1 ) { $sums{ $_ } += $F[ $_ ]; } END { $sums{ $#F } = $F[ -1 ]; say join ",", map { $sums{ $_ } } sort keys %sums; }'
```

Answer (score 1):

A modified version based on the solution you linked:

```
#!/bin/bash

colnum=6
filename="temp"

for ((i=2;i<$colnum;++i))
do
  sum=$(cut -d ',' -f $i $filename | paste -sd+ | bc)
  echo -n $sum','
done
head -1 $filename | cut -d ',' -f $colnum
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash


while IFS=, read -a arr
do
        for((i=1;i<${#arr[*]}-1;i++))
        do
                ((farr[$i]=${farr[$i]}+${arr[$i]}))
        done
        farr[$i]=${arr[$i]}
done < file
(IFS=,;echo "${farr[*]}")
```