# Summing columns of data (single digits)

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-coreutils

I'm looking for a quick way to add rows of data like

```
3333456332....
3334456332....
3343446332....
3331355332....
```

(but longer) and add it up per digit to this result:

```
12 12 13 11 15 19 22 12 12 4
```

Is this possible with a one-liner? Or more complex?

Comment: I think you mean columns!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956264/how-to-sum-each-column-in-a-file-using-bash

Comment: Note that "Linux command line" is a misnomer here. Linux is a kernel and doesn't have a "command line" (except the one line passed by the bootloader). You probably meant to ask how to do this in a Unix (or POSIX) shell environment. And if you're using GNU Bash, GNU awk, GNU sed, GNU coreutils, etc. (e.g. if you're on Debian, Ubuntu, or any other of the dozens of GNU/Linux distros), then this would be a case where "GNU" alone is technically more correct than "Linux" alone, in case GNU/Linux is too wordy. :-)

Comment: @TaylanUB I've edited the title and tags, hopefully it is a little clearer now.

Answer (score 3):

How about a nice bit of awk:

```
awk -v FS="" '{for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) a[i]+=$i} END {for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) printf "%d ", a[i] }' file
```

This creates an array `a` that accumulates all of the sums for each digit. At the `END` of the file, go through the array and print all of the sums.

The `FS` variable is important here, as it means that each digit on the line is treated as a separate field.

Output:

```
12 12 13 11 15 19 23 12 12 8
```

#### update

The above code won't print a newline after the sums, which may be what you want. As suggested in the comments by [fedorqui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui), one way round that would be to do:

```
awk -v FS="" '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) a[i]+=$i} END {for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) printf "%d%s", a[i], (i<NF?" ":"\n") }' file
```

Which prints a space between all of the values, then a newline at the end.

Alternatively, if you like concatenating strings, you could do:

```
awk -v FS="" '{for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) a[i]+=$i} END{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) s=s a[i] " "; print s}' file
```

Which first builds up a string `s` and then `print`s it. `print` will add the newline by default for you.

---

Inspired by [choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23806416/2088135), here's an alternative version using Perl:

```
perl -F'' -wane 'pop @F; $i=0; $s[$i++]+=$_ for @F }{ print "@s\n"' file
```

as in awk, set the field delimiter to `''`. Use the "autosplit" switch `-a` which creates the array `@F`, each element containing one digit.

The last element of `@F` is the newline `"\n"`, so `pop` removes it. The array `@s` keeps all of the sums in. The `-n` switch means that the whole command is surrounded in `while (<>) { ... }`, so using the `}{` "eskimo operator" effectively creates an `END` block. <del>By setting the special variable `$"` to a space</del> `$"` is a space by default, so the array can be printed in one go, with each element separated by a space.

Comment: Good one. In the `END{}` you can make use of `printf "%d%s", a[i], (i==NF?"\n":" ")` to print a new line at the end and a space in other cases.

Comment: @fedorqui thanks, I've added your suggestion (and another of my own).

Answer (score 2):

Here's my version

```
grep -o . | pr -4 -t | sed -r 's/\s+/+/g' | bc | xargs
```

Comment: I guess you meant `grep -o . file`? Unfortunately this only works for files with 4 lines. I guess you could change it to `pr -$(wc -l < file) -t` in the middle!

Comment: Right, I didn't want to clutter such an elegant solution :) I assume data comes from stdin.

Comment: It certainly is an interesting way of solving the problem. Perhaps it would benefit from some explanation of each step.

Comment: There are some limitations of course and you may need additional pr parameters depending on the size of a matrix. But here's how it works: with grep -o we transform matrix to single dimensional array,then back to transposed matrix with pr, convert each row "a b" to "a+b" and calculate sum of each row with bc. We now have sums one per row and we transpose it to one row with xargs (with no parameters it reads parameters from stdin and executes echo arg1 arg2 ...).

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ne 'chomp; 1 == $. ? @s : @F = split //; $_ += shift @F for @s  }{ print "@s\n"'
```

Comment: Nice answer (not that I understand it completely!), although there is an extra `0` at the end of the output. Using the `-w` shows some warnings, which I think are related. I added a Perl version to my answer which you might like :)

Comment: @TomFenech: You can prepend `chomp;` to the perl code (updated) to avoid the problems.

Comment: Nice. Looking at it again, I think I get it now. The first bit in particular is tricky! You can get rid of the warnings using: `'chomp; @F = split //; if (1 == $.) { @s = @F; next } $_ += shift @F for @s }{ print "@s\n"' file`, as this avoids `shift`ing `@F` when it is empty.

Comment: @TomFenech: Or simply `perl -wne 'chomp; 1 == $. ? @s : @F = split //; next unless @F; $_ += shift @F for @s  }{ print "@s\n"'`, but who cares about warnings in one-liners...