# Bash loop that calculates the sums of columns

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a loop in Bash that prints the sum of every column in a file. These columns are separated by tabs.  What I have so far is this:

```
cols() {
  count=$(grep -c $'\t' $1)
  for n in $(seq 1 $count) ;do
    cat $FILE | awk '{sum+=$1} END{print "sum=",sum}'
  done
}
```

But this only prints out the sum of the first column.  How can I do this for every column?

Comment: As an aside: Pasting your code at [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) will give you tips on improving your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to sum each column in a file using bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956264/how-to-sum-each-column-in-a-file-using-bash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach does the job, but it is somehow overkill: you are counting the number of columns, then `cat`ting the file and calling `awk`, while `awk` alone can do all of it:

```
awk -F"\t" '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) sum[i]+=$i} END {for (i in sum) print i, sum[i]}' file
```

This takes advantage of `NF` that stores the number of fields a line has (which is what you were doing with `count=$(grep -c $'\t' $1)`). Then, it is just a matter of looping through the fields and sum to every element on the array, where `sum[i]` contains the sum for the column `i`. Finally, it loops through the result and writes its values.

Why isn't your approach suming a given column? Because when you say:

```
for n in $(seq 1 $count) ;do
    cat $FILE | awk '{sum+=$1} END{print "sum=",sum}'
done
```

You are always using `$1` as the element to sum. Instead, you should pass the value `$n` to awk by using something like:

```
awk -v col="$n" '{sum+=$col} END{print "sum=",sum}' $FILE # no need to cat $FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a bash builtin only solution, this would work:

```
declare -i i l
declare -ai la sa=()
while read -d$'\t' -ra la; do
    for ((l=${#la[@]}, i=0; i<l; sa[i]+=la[i], ++i)); do :; done
done < file
(IFS=$'\t'; echo "${sa[*]}")
```

The performance of this should be decent, but quite a bit slower than something like awk.