# Sum of multiple columns in bash

Tags: perl, bash, calculated-columns

I have an O/p file below and I'm looking for a bash and Perl solution:

```
Aggregate               total   used      avail   capacity
aggr0                   100     59       41      41%
aggr1                   200     100      100     50%
aggr2                   300     150     150      50%
aggr3                   400     200      200     50%
```

I would like to calculate the sum of all individual column except Col-1. The final state should look like this:

```
Aggregate               total   used      avail   capacity
aggr0                   100     59       41      41%
aggr1                   200     100      100     50%
aggr2                   300     150     150      50%
aggr3                   400     200      200     50%
=========================================================
                        1000   509       460   50.9%  (Used % of all aggr's)
```

Comment: U can find your answer here 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096259/bash-command-to-sum-a-column-of-numbers'

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw glad you referenced this answer, Thanks! it's interesting but doesn't quite meet requirements, I feel

Comment: @Vorsprung i thought so, but the title of the question is quite the same. And the question i referred to has many answers so with a combination of them it should be possible to get the answer needed here.

Answer (score 0):

infile is the file with the data in it

```
perl -ape 'next if $.==1; for my $i (1..4) { $s[$i] += $F[$i]; } END { $s[4]=sprintf("%.2f%%",$s[2]/$s[1]*100); $"="\t";print "total\t\t @s\n";}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl is probably more suitable to this task, but it can be done from bash too :)

```
    tail -n +2 my_op_file.txt | while read n c1 c2 c3 c4;do
        total=$(($total + $c1 ))
        used=$(($used + $c2 ))
        avail=$(($avail + $c3 ))
        capacity=$(($capacity + ${c4%%%}))
        echo $total $used $avail $capacity
    done
```

Comment: Thanks Mzzl, but couple of issues:

Comment: 1: 100 59 41 41
300 159 141 91
600 309 291 141
1000 509 491 191
 Column Row:4 Column:4 should be $used/$total*100

Comment: 2: the heading R1 and C1 is missing in the final O/P