# How to sum numbers with linux

Tags: linux, bash

I do a `cat results.txt | grep eval` and I get

```
eval: -2.72907
baseline eval (random): -0.031584202184
eval: 0.807805
baseline eval (random): 0.0227601966463
eval: 2.0625
baseline eval (random): 0.0138953249621
```

How do I sum `eval` and `baseline eval` separately with linux commands from the command line?

Comment: Have you got `bc` installed? It's a calculator in itself, it'd probably be easier to use that than bash.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash command to sum a column of numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096259/bash-command-to-sum-a-column-of-numbers)

Comment: Useless use of cat: use `grep eval results.txt` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Awk can do it

```
% grep eval results.txt | awk -F: '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(i in a)print i ": " a[i]}'
eval: 0.141235
baseline eval (random): 0.00507132
```

Better yet, as Johnsyweb mentioned in a comment, let [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) do the searching too:

```
awk -F: '/eval/{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(i in a)print i ": " a[i]}' results.txt
```

Comment: well when I see your answer, I realize that, either you or me, have misunderstood the question... `sum eval and baseline eval separately`... I may be wrong...

Comment: `awk -F: '/eval/ {a[$1]+=$2}END{for(i in a)print i ": " a[i]}' results.txt` , surely!?

Comment: @Kent: This ***does*** sum the two separately.

Comment: @Johnsyweb I know what the awk line does. I understood the Q as `sum(eval and baseline eval) separately`... I could be on the wrong way... :(