# piping the output of a cut operation to bc

Tags: bash, cut, bc

Is it at all possible to get `bc` to compute based on the output of a `cut` command?

Lets say I have the following column based file:

```
PAK_01896       PAU_03392       75.8    149     32      1       1       145     1       149     *       *
PAK_02014       PAU_03392       69.8    149     45      0       1       149     1       149     *       *
PAU_02074       PAU_03392       77.2    149     30      1       1       145     1       149     *       *
PAU_02206       PAU_03392       69.1    149     46      0       1       149     1       149     *       *
PAU_02775       PAU_03392       79.2    149     31      0       1       149     1       149     *       *
PAK_02606       PAU_03392       78.5    149     32      0       1       149     1       149     *       *
PAU_01961       PAU_03392       67.1    149     49      0       1       149     1       149     *       *
PAK_03203       PAU_03392       95.3    149     7       0       1       149     1       149     *       *
PLT_01716       PAU_03392       76.5    149     35      0       1       149     1       149     *       *
PLT_01758       PAU_03392       79.2    149     31      0       1       149     1       149     *       *
PAU_03392       PAU_03392       100.0   149     0       0       1       149     1       149     *       *
PLT_01696       PAU_03392       78.5    149     32      0       1       149     1       149     *       *
PLT_02424       PAU_03392       78.5    149     32      0       1       149     1       149     *       *
PLT_01736       PAU_03392       77.2    149     34      0       1       149     1       149     *       *
PLT_02568       PAU_03392       67.1    149     49      0       1       149     1       149     *       *
PAK_01787       PAU_03392       66.4    149     50      0       1       149     1       149     *       *
```

I'd like to be able to perform some calculation on certain fields, for example something to the effect of summing and/or averaging the 3rd column. In my head I first thought to try this:

```
 cut -f3 column_based_file.txt | bc
```

But perhaps unsurprisingly this just returns the value of each item in column 3.

I know there are workable solutions to this in threads such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096259/bash-command-to-sum-a-column-of-numbers) that I could use, but since cut has been my go-to way of manipulating column based data in bash for a while, I'm just wondering if it is at all possible? Maybe `bc` has some flag for reading in one line at a time and storing them etc.

**EDIT** There are some great solutions in the threads suggested, and in the answers given. Out of curiosity, since that's how I'd originally thought to do it, does anyone have a `cut` and `bc` based solution (if for some reason perl or awk weren't available perhaps?)

Comment: See: [Shell command to sum integers, one per line?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/450799/3776858)

Comment: Ah great, didn't come across that one as I was looking by `cut` and `bc` keywords.

Comment: `sum=$(sed -r "s/ +/\t/g" sumavg.csv | cut -f 3 | paste -s -d + - | bc)` for the sum. (I need the sed step to squash sequences of space into one tab) and  `lc=$( wc -l sumavg.csv | cut -f1 -d " " )` for the line count (take care that the last data line ends with newline) and then the outputs: `echo $sum` and `echo "scale=3; $sum / $lc " | bc` for the average

Comment: @JoeHealey: should I reopen the question?

Comment: No I think the close is valid @Cyrus, Lars solution is interesting but confirms what I had suspected, that there is no way to implement a solution using only `cut` and `bc` without invoking any other program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use awk. It is in my humble opinion better suited for this task. Say your data is stored in `sumavg.csv`, then this GNU awk script (`sumavg.awk`) shows sum and average of the third field:

```
    {s += $3 }
END {print "Sum:", s, " Avg: ", s / FNR}
```

Run it with the command `awk -f sumavg.awk sumavg.csv`.

`$3` is the third field on each line, `END` is a special pattern its action is executed in the end, `FNR` gives the number of rows in the file.

Comment: Ah that's very nice! I really have never had proper cause to get to grips with `awk` but I suspect I should do so sooner rather than later...

Comment: If I wanted the awk script to print the name of the file in the output, how would I implement that? using `END {print "File was:" '$3' etc... } throws a syntax error. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong based on other threads.

Comment: Use `print FILENAME, "Sum:", s, " Avg: ", s / FNR` in the END section.