# How to get audio length for all audios using sox?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, audio, sox

I can do `soxi -d *` to get audio length information in hours, minutes, and seconds.

However it would only give me info on the individual audio length.

If I wanted to see the audio length for the entire folder, how can I accomplish such task?

like when you do "wc -w" it shows the sum of everything at the end. Is there a flag or something I can integrate with `soxi`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

soxi -T *

from the man file

> -T     Used with multiple files; changes the behaviour of -s, -d and -D to
> display the total across all given files.  Note that when used with -s with files > with different sampling rates, this is of questionable value.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have .wav files in directory.

For single file use `soxi -D ...`, and then sum values with `bc` ([how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096259/bash-command-to-sum-a-column-of-numbers))
Use any of this commands to get total in seconds:

```
# in seconds
soxi -D *.wav | awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}' | bc

# in seconds 
soxi -D *.wav | paste -sd+ - | bc

# in minutes
soxi -D *.wav | awk '{s+=$1}END{print s/60}' | bc

# in hours
soxi -D *.wav | awk '{s+=$1}END{print s/60/60}' | bc
```

Answer (score 0):

does it **have** to be `soxi` ? if you're willing to use `ffprobe` as part of `ffmpeg`, here's how it scanned a folder of mine with different file types - `.mp3`, `AAC` in `.m4a`, and `FLAC` :

> making the lazy assumption that your filenames don't contain the equal sign (`"="`) in their names. if they do, adjust the `csv=s=` option accordingly

```
   gfind . -type f -not -name ".*" -print0 |

   parallel -0 --bar -N 1 -j 8 

     'ffprobe -hide_banner   -v 0 
              -select_streams a:0
             
      -show_entries format=format_long_name,size,filename,duration
      -of csv=s="=":p=0:nk=0
      -i {}'

./genieaudio_93508443_.lossless.mp3
MP2/3 (MPEG audio layer 2/3)
232.150204
9287144

./genieaudio_16277926_.aac.flac.m4a
QuickTime / MOV
232.181000
63572859

./genieaudio_16277926_.lossless.mp3
MP2/3 (MPEG audio layer 2/3)
232.280816
92923682/3)
250.096327
10004990

./genieaudio_79412303_.lossless.mp3
MP2/3 (MPEG audio layer 2/3)
250.383673
10016483

./genieaudio_16108705_.192k.mp3.flac
raw FLAC
251.122000
55480793

./backupgenieaudio_16108705_test1.192k.mp3
MP2/3 (MPEG audio layer 2/3)
251.928000
6046272

./genieaudio_16108705_test1.192k.mp3
MP2/3 (MPEG audio layer 2/3)
251.928000
6046893

./genieaudio_16108705_test2.192k.mp3
MP2/3 (MPEG audio layer 2/3)
251.928000
6046848

./genieaudio_16254360_192_b.mp3
MP2/3 (MPEG audio layer 2/3)
255.111837
6123354

./genieaudio_16268888_.192k.mp3.flac
raw FLAC
259.442979
55115022
```