# How to get the length of the sum of audio files using sox?

Tags: bash, shell, audio, sox

I have a script such as following

```
DIR=$1
ls $1 |sort -R |tail -$5 |while read file; do
    soxi -d $1$file
done
```

and it gives me an output like

```
00:40:35.18
00:43:41.23
01:04:19.64
00:59:41.92
00:51:16.32
```

As you can see, the program picks a random file (audio) from the folder and checks the time for each file. However, I need the sum of the length of all the audios.

How can I get the total number of audio files?

Comment: Use `soxi -D` to show duration in seconds, so it's easy to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `soxi`'s `-D` option to get durations in (fractional) seconds
- Use `bc` to add the seconds to a total
- [Don't use `ls` to list files](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- [Don't pipe into a while loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024), since you will need to set variables, and they would be lost after the loop.

So here is an example, selecting 3 random "*.wav" files under some directory

```
#!/bin/bash
total=0
dir=/some/dir
while read -r f; do
    d=$(soxi -D "$f")
    echo "$d s. in $f"
    total=$(echo "$total + $d" | bc)
done < <(find "$dir" -iname "*.wav" | sort -R | head -3)

echo "Total : $total seconds"
```

If you can use [Mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) instead of sox, you can get the durations in milliseconds, and use standard shell arithmetic for the additions. It also supports more audio formats.

```
#!/bin/bash
total=0
dir=/some/dir
while read -r f; do
    d=$(mediainfo --Output='General;%Duration%' "$f")
    ((total += d))
done < <(find "$dir" -iname "*.wav")

echo "Total : $total ms. or $((total/1000)) seconds"
```

(that 2nd example is without the random selection, for simplicity)

Answer (score 4):

You can combine `-D` and `-T` for the total length in seconds, e.g.

```
soxi -DT *.wav
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64826967/5090928