# What does "-sd+" do in bash's paste command?

Tags: bash

Apologies if this question is answered somewhere. If so, I will be more than happy to remove or edit this question. But [I have searched long and hard for an answer to this](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%22-sd%2B%22%22+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F&lr=&as_qdr=all&sxsrf=ALeKk0278IHYmHPFNqdmGu0ZaRBQBJbrVQ%3A1619588323437&ei=4_SIYN2TGqmt0PEP5p-K0AI&oq=%22%22-sd%2B%22%22+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANQpTZYkE5gzFBoAHAAeACAAWWIAZ4DkgEDNC4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwidkc3VnKDwAhWpFjQIHeaPAioQ4dUDCA4&uact=5) (using Google [since symbols don't work in StackExchange's search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249848/search-using-symbols-is-broken)) but have been unable to find anything.

When searching for a command to sum numbers I stumbled upon [this StackExchange answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096259/bash-command-to-sum-a-column-of-numbers/3096575#3096575) that said the solution laid in a set of piped commands like the following:

```
<cmd> | paste -sd+ | bc
```

This seems to be correct, however, as a newer user to Bash scripting I have never seen the `paste` command be used with the options `-sd+` before. The `-s` makes sense as the serial command, but [everywhere](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/paste-command-in-linux-with-examples/) [I](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-paste-command/) [look](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paste_(Unix)) says that the `-d` (delimiter) option must be used with a string after it to indicate the string that will be used as the delimiter. (e.g. something like `-d "|"`.) Even the manual seems to indicate this:

```
Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
 -d, --delimiters=LIST   reuse characters from LIST instead of TABs
 -s, --serial            paste one file at a time instead of in parallel
 -z, --zero-terminated    line delimiter is NUL, not newline
   --help     display this help and exit
   --version  output version information and exit
```

However, the command from the answer listed above does not have a string after it. Instead, it just has a `+` symbol (which I assume is for the arithmetic calculation in `bc`) and whitespace. And based on the context of the answer, the `+` symbol does not seem to be the new delimiter (espcially considering there is no space between it and `d`). What is the benefit of having `-d` attached if there is no delimiter specified?

**So could someone please break down for me what the `paste -sd+` command does?** Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`paste -sd+` is just a shorter way of writing `paste -s -d +` or `paste -s -d "+"`. So it *is* indeed the new delimiter.

```
$ printf '%s\n' 1 2 | paste -sd+
1+2
```

Comment: OH. I misunderstood how the delimiter worked in `paste`, in that case. I thought it was a delimiter for the **incoming** data that it would separate by. Now I understand, thank you!

Comment: (I'll accept your answer as soon as the cooldown on StackOverflow lets me)