# Add thousands of numbers stored in second 'column' in text files?

Tags: linux, command-line, shell

I've got a file with 400k+ numbers, each with a filename and its size in separate lines and I need to add them up to get a total.

See: https://superuser.com/questions/195493/unix-recursive-directory-listing-with-full-pathname-of-file-and-filesize

```
filename1 size1
filename2 size2
```

Its not going to be a very large number ... < ~50,000,000

They're all integers, no decimal points, none of them > 120

Need to do this on a standard linux command line. I can modify the script used to generate this output, which is:

```
find full_path_to_your_directory -type f -printf '%p %s\n'
```

Comment: Sheesh - found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450799/linux-command-to-sum-integers-one-per-line in the related box on the right _just_ right after posting this...! Looks promising!

Comment: Indeed, I wish the related sidebar could be [incorporated when asking a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42878/54262).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this :

```
find . -type f -printf '%p %s\n' | perl -n -a -e '$sum+=$S[1]; print "$sum\n"'
```

which displays the running total.

```
find . -type f -printf '%p %s\n' | perl -n -a -e '$sum+=$F[1]; print "$sum\n"' | tail -n 1
```

will just show the total.

With awk it is slightly more compact :

```
find . -type f -printf '%p %s\n' | awk '{ sum+=$2}; END { print sum}'
```

Comment: Later Perl version has `-a` (autosplit), so there's no need to use `split` explicitly.

Comment: @user131527 Great, I'll try it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -printf '%p %s\n'  | awk '{sum+=$NF}END{print sum}'
```

If you want to use Perl,

```
find . -type f -printf '%p %s\n' | perl -ane '$sum+=$F[1];END{print "$sum\n"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need the filename to sum the sizes:

```
find path -type f -printf '%s\n' | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'
```