# Simplest way to total up columns?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv

I have a PHP script that imports up to 10 or so different CSV files. Each row of each file contains bank account info, including balance. After I've imported all the CSV data into my database, I'd like to make sure the data got in there correctly by comparing the total account balance in the database to the total account balance of the CSV files.

I see at least a few options:

1. Manually total up all the account balances in Excel - yuck.
2. Write a PHP script to read each CSV file and total up the account balances - also yuck.
3. Some third option that I hope exists. It would be amazing if I could do something like:

   `excel --file="cd.csv" | sum --column="E"`

That's obviously not a real thing but hopefully you get the idea. Using some combination of PHP, MySQL, Linux commands, Excel and/or any other tools, is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: u can change php to accept $argv (cli mode) or a simple bash `total=0; col=9;for i in `cut -d ' ' cd.csv -f $col`; do let total=$i+$total; done; echo $total`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't have to complete answer for you, but AWK should be able to solve your problem: Have a look at these 2 posts:

https://superuser.com/questions/53652/transforming-csv-file-using-sed

[Shell command to sum integers, one per line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450799/linux-command-to-sum-integers-one-per-line)

I'm not enough of a AWK expert to give the solution, but perhaps someone else can help us here.

Another option (which you may also consider yuck) is to use a library like [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Comment: It looks like I'll go with `awk`.

Comment: Update: this seems to have worked: `cat file.csv | awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{s+=$2} END {print s}'` (That totals up the second column.)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the CSV file using `fgetcsv()` which converts each line to an array of values. You can accumulate the value of the array element containing the balance as you move thru each iteration until you get the sum total. Use `glob` to get the list of CSV files in a folder.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have to "manually" total up the account balances, if you can use Excel functions from your application, the Excel formula in VBA would be:

```
Application.Sum(Range("A:A"))
```

where A:A is for column A.

Comment: Could use COM from PHP if running on windows, but he is running on Linux it seems

Comment: I am running Linux. However, that's not to say it wouldn't help to automate some of the process in Windows and then bring the results into Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [CSVFix](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/) with it's summary option.  It will get you more data than you need, but should be easy to use.

Otherwise, this sounds like a good use for Awk.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just automagically total up the account balances in excel with a formula and export them with the rest of the data?

Comment: I could do that. It wouldn't be ideal (I prefer total automation) but it may turn out to be the simplEST solution.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a different angle: Make use of the [MySql CSV engine](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/csv-storage-engine.html) to expose your CSV files to Mysql and then do a normal SQL SUM.

See also: [The CSV Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/csv-storage-engine.html)

Comment: I like this idea. I will look into it more to see if it's a viable option.