# Unix command line : How to get the total size of modified files in the last 30 days

Tags: file, unix, command, size

I want to know how to get the total size of the modified files in the last 30 days.

I have found this command who onlye give me the list of the modified files in the last 30 days.

```
find . -name '*' -mtime -30
```

It is useful but I want to know the TOTAL size of this list.

Can someone help getting through this please?

Comment: I've flagged to move this question to Super User, the stack exchange site where you're more (most?) likely to get help with this question.

Comment: @Li-aungYip Definitely not. The correct one would be: http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Let_Me_Be : I prefer Super User - it's more active. But it appears SO has delivered on this question anyway, so no matter. ;)

Comment: `-name '*'` can be removed. It matches all files and since all predicates are anded together, anding with a true predicate is useless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps this would do:

```
find . -mtime -30 -exec ls -l {} \;| awk '{s+=$5} END {print "Total SIZE: " s}'
```

Comment: None what so ever. Just a copy n paste error from the original statement. I've removed it from the example. Well spotted Jens!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by having find output the size of each file, then [total them up with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450799/linux-command-to-sum-integers-one-per-line)

```
find . -name '*' -mtime -30 -printf '%s\n' | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try piping the output of your working find command to `du` to see if the output its satisfactory.  You can use the `du` switches `-c` to produce a total, and optionally `-h` to make it human readable.

eg:

```
<your command> | du -c
```

becomes:

```
find . -name '*' -mtime -30 | du -c
```

If you only want the total line:

```
find . -name '*' -mtime -30 | du -c | grep "total"
```

Produces output:

```
360     total
```

and using `du -ch` produces:

```
360K    total
```