# Why is my code not working as I want it to?

Tags: bash

I have this code:

```
total=0;
ps -u $(whoami) --no-headers | awk {'print $1'} | while read line; 
                          do vrednost=$(pmap $line | tail -n1 | column -t | cut -d" " -f3 | tr "K" " "); 
                          total=$(( vrednost + total ))
                          echo $total 
                          done
                          echo total: $total
```

As you can see, my code sums usage of all my processes. When I echo my total every time in while, it is working ok, but at the end... When i want total to be a value (`echo total: $total`) it is still zero. but before (in `while`) has right value.

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but you can declare `total` to have the 'integer' attribute using `declare -i total=0`, then simply say `total+=$vrednost`.

Comment: @chepner: You can also do `(( total += vrednost ))` with or without declaring the variable as an integer. To me, doing this makes it clear that you mean addition and not concatenation.

Answer (score 3):

[BASH FAQ #24: "I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

```
#!/bin/bash
while read ...
do
  ...
done < <(ps ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, pick and choose. You can either do it in BASH or AWK, but don't do both. You've seen a BASH example, here's an AWK example:

```
ps  -e -o user -o vsz | awk -v USER="$(whoami)" '
    BEGIN {TOTAL = 0}
    END {print "Total is " TOTAL}
    {
        if ($1 == USER) {
            TOTAL += $2
        }
    }
'
```

Awk is like a programming language that assumes a loop (like `perl -n`) and processes each line in the file. Each field (normally separated by whitespace) is given a `$` variable. The first is `$1`, the second is `$2`, etc.

The `-v` option allows me to define an awk variable (in this case `USER`) before I run awk.

The `BEGIN` line is what I want to do before I run my `awk` script. In this case, initialize `TOTAL` to zero. (NOTE: This really isn't necessary since undefined variables automatically are given a value of zero). The `END` line is what I want to do afterwards. In this case, print out my total.

So, if the first field ($1) is equal to my user, I'll add the second field (the vsize) to my total.

All Awk programs are surrounded by `{...}` and they usually have single quotes around them to prevent shell interpolation of `$1`, etc.

Comment: For readability, I prefer putting the `END` block at the ... end. Also, there's no need for an `if` statement - put your condition outside the main block braces: `$1 == USER {TOTAL += $2}`

Comment: +1, but note that there's no real need for the BEGIN.  Just use `TOTAL + 0` in END to ensure `0` is printed rather than an empty string.  Variables are autovivified to 0.

Comment: I like putting the BEGIN block and END block at the beginning, so people will see them. Otherwise, people miss them. Yes, this is more code than needed. However, I wanted to emphasize the language part. Awk is a programming language with lots of features. I could have simplified the whole thing with a one liner:  `ps -u $(whoami) --no-header -o vsz | awk 'END {print "Total is " TOTAL} {TOTAL += $1}'`, but again I wanted to emphasize the Awk language.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash
total=0;
for line in `ps -u $(whoami) --no-headers | awk {'print $1'}`; 
do 
  vrednost=$(pmap $line | tail -n1 | column -t | cut -d" " -f3 | tr "K" " "); 
      total=$(( $vrednost + $total ))
      echo $total 
done
echo "total: $total"
```

Comment: ps -u $(whoami) --no-headers | awk {'print $1'};

it says that this has an error...i don't know how to fix it :/

Comment: See [my comment on chepner's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824465/why-is-my-code-not-working-as-i-want-it-to#comment14094657_10825147).

Answer (score 0):

Let's cut down on the number of extra processes you need :)

```
declare -i total=0
for size in $( ps -u $(whoami) --no-header -o vsz ); do
    total+=$size
done
echo $total
```

First, use various options for `ps` to generate the desired list of process sizes, in kilobytes. Iterate over that list using a bash for-loop, keeping a running total in a parameter declared with the 'integer' attribute for easy arithmetic. The desired sum is now in `total`, ready for whatever use you need. The sum includes the memory used by the `ps` process itself.

Using `while` (Dennis' suggestion) and avoiding process substitution (William's suggestion):

```
ps -u $(whoami) --no-header -o vsz | { 
  while read -r var; do
    ((total+=$var))
  done
  echo $total
}
```

(For real one-liner, here's a `dc` command that I borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/453290/1126841:

```
ps -u $(whoami) --no-header -o vsz | dc -f - -e '[+z1<r]srz1<rp'
```

This sum includes the memory used by the `ps` and `dc` commands themselves.)

Comment: Most of the time, it's incorrect to use `for` to iterate over a command substitution. Because of this, it's good to be in the habit of using `while read -r var` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ignacio's answer is fine, but process substitution is not portable.  And there is a simpler solution.  You need to echo the total in the same subshell in which it is calculated:

```
... | { while read line; do ...; done; echo total: $total; }
```