# How can I make awk not use scientific notation when printing small values?

Tags: awk

In the following awk command

```
 awk '{sum+=$1; ++n} END {avg=sum/n; print "Avg monitoring time = "avg}' file.txt
```

what should I change to remove scientific notation output (very small values displayed as 1.5e-05) ?

I was not able to succeed with the OMFT variable.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You should use the [`printf` AWK statement](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf.html).  That way you can specify padding, precision, etc.  In your case, the [`%f` control letter](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Control-Letters.html#Control-Letters) seems the more appropriate.

Comment: For those who don't often use awk and forget the syntax, here is an example: `echo ""|awk '{printf "%.2f", 1566666666/50}'`

Comment: Also note that even if you're summing up integers, [you probably want to use `%f`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25245025/120999).

Comment: @AaronR. If you don't need `awk` to take any input, you could do `awk 'BEGIN{printf "%.2f", 1566666666/50}'` to use your example.  The default selector is `$0`, which is the standard input, & waits for a newline in standard input before running, but `BEGIN` doesn't  wait for anything on standard input.  Also, to just output a newline, you can just do `echo`, you don't need `echo ""`.

Comment: You can use eg. `awk '{print sprintf("%.10f", $1/$2), $2}'`

Answer (score 16):

> I was not able to succeed with the OMFT variable.

It is actually `OFMT` (**o**utput**f**or**m**a**t**), so for example:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFMT="%f";print 0.000015}'
```

will output:

```
0.000015
```

as opposed to:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print 0.000015}'
```

which output:

```
1.5e-05
```

[GNU AWK manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/OFMT.html) says that if you want to be POSIX-compliant it should be *floating-point conversion specification*.

Answer (score 5):

Setting `-v OFMT='%f'` (without having to embed it into my awk statement) worked for me in the case where all I wanted from awk was to sum columns of arbitrary floating point numbers.

As the OP found, awk produces exponential notation with very small numbers,

```sh
$ some_accounting_widget | awk '{sum+=$0} END{print sum+0}'
8.992e-07  # Not useful to me
```

Setting OFMT for fixed that, but also rounded too aggressively,

```sh
$ some_accounting_widget | awk -v OFMT='%f' '{sum+=$0} END{print sum+0}'
0.000001   # Oops. Rounded off too much. %f rounds to 6 decimal places by default.
```

Specifying the number of decimal places got me what I needed,

```sh
$ some_accounting_widget | awk -v OFMT='%.10f' '{sum+=$0} END{print sum+0}'
0.0000008992    # Perfect.
```