# How can I use plink/Unix to convert data from scientific notation to decimal?

Tags: unix, scientific-notation

I work with genetic data.  I just found a supercomputer to help with genetic analysis, but I need to convert the data to exactly the format the super computer wants: two columns, one with chromosome information and one with p-value.  The p-value column must not have any letters, but some of the data I have is in scientific notation, like so:

```
rs191895619 1.052e-05
rs140779862 0.4406
rs11127542 0.9771
rs112183333 0.02569
rs191067167 0.427
rs111321342 1.042e-05
```

which puts several E's in the column that must not have letters in it.

I tried to use `grep` to move them into their own file using `grep "*e*" filename.txt > outputfilename.txt` as well as `grep "*e-05" filename.txt > outputfilename.txt` but it gave me a blank output file both times, and even if all 5000 lines of scientifically notated data had moved into their own file, I don't know how to change the data to decimal notation except by editing each line individually, which would take several days for each file.

Is there a command I can give to plink so that the data it gives me is not in scientific notation in the first place?  Or a command I can use in plink or Unix to convert the scientific notation I have into decimal notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk` to convert scientific to decimal:

```
awk '{printf "%s %f\n", $1, $2}' file
```

Outputs:

```
rs191895619 0.000011
rs140779862 0.440600
rs11127542 0.977100
rs112183333 0.025690
rs191067167 0.427000
rs111321342 0.000010
```

You can adjust the precision by changing `%f` part in `printf`.

---

See also:

- [How remove scientific notation in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714155/how-remove-scientific-notation-in-awk)