# Sum values in a file with a for-loop

Tags: bash, file, for-loop, sum

I have a file which contains values in `KB` and `MB`. How can I, in a `for`-loop calculate the *sum of the values in MB for both `MB` and `KB`* ?

For MB, This gives me the values and then I need to sum those:

```
cat usage_1.12.2015_31.12.2015.xls.csv | grep MB | awk -F '"' '{print $4}'  | awk '{print $1}'
```

Output:

```
17
16
13
17
14
3
3
12
10
8
6
10
```

KB

```
  student@student-vm:~/Downloads$ cat usage1.12.2015_31.12.2015.xls.csv | grep KB
    "2015/12/28 14:15:46","109 KB",,0
    "2015/12/28 14:13:47","331 KB",,0
    "2015/12/21 11:01:34","762 KB",,0
    "2015/12/20 19:51:40","253 KB",,0
    "2015/12/07 07:18:50","81 KB",,0
    "2015/12/03 14:56:06","407 KB",,0
```

MB

```
student@student-vm:~/Downloads$ cat usage1.12.2015_31.12.2015.xls.csv | grep MB
"2015/12/06 15:54:47","10 MB",,0
"2015/12/06 09:43:02","4 MB",,0
"2015/12/05 21:39:04","21 MB",,0
"2015/12/05 09:17:11","18 MB",,0
"2015/12/04 21:57:49","70 MB",,0
"2015/12/04 17:09:45","1 MB",,0
"2015/12/04 16:47:05","17 MB",,0
```

Comment: replace KB by * 1, MB by * 1024, etc. and `eval` the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using awk here:

```
awk -F'"?,"?' '{ split($2, a, / /); if (a[2] == "KB") a[1] /= 1000; sum += a[1] } 
END { print sum }' file
```

The `-F` switch is used to split the input on commas, optionally surrounded by quotes. Split the second field `$2` on spaces `/ /` into the array `a`. Divide the first part `a[1]` (the number) by 1000 if the second part `a[2]` is `KB`. Accumulate a sum of the values and once the file has been fully processed, print the value in the `END` block.

Comment: The code worked, but I have no idea how it works. :)

Comment: Would you like me to explain some part of it more clearly?

Comment: That would be helpfull for everyone I guess.

Answer (score 0):

First get the column values so that you have just lines like `1 MB`, `50 KB` etc., then you can do this kind of thing to get the number of bytes:

1. Replace spaces with empty strings (using `sed` notation):

   ```
   s/ //
   ```
2. Convert megabytes to kilobytes (add three zeros if using ISO units, `*1024KB` and send the result of step 3 through `bc` if it's kibibytes; you can also do this for GB, TB etc.):

   ```
   s/MB/000KB/
   ```
3. Convert kilobytes to bytes:

   ```
   s/KB/000/
   ```
4. [Sum the numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/450821/96588)
5. Convert bytes to megabytes:

   ```
   bc <<< "${sum} / 1000000"
   ```