# Sum out of grep -c

Tags: linux

I am trying to find the number an even occured in my log file.

Command:

```
grep -Eo "2016-08-30" applciationLog.log* -c
```

Output:

```
 applciationLog.log.1:0
 applciationLog.log.2:0
 applciationLog.log.3:0
 applciationLog.log.4:0
 applciationLog.log.5:7684
 applciationLog.log.6:9142
 applciationLog.log.7:8699
 applciationLog.log.8:0
```

What I actually need is sum of all these values 7684 + 9142 + 8699 = 25525. Any suggestion I can do it? Anything I can append to the grep to enable it.

Any help or pointers are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: grep's job is to find things. adding up numbers is not its job. you feed grep's output to awk/sed and do the addition there.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep your grep command, pipe its output to awk, the quick and dirty way is down here:

```
grep -Eo "aaa" -c aaa.txt bbb.txt -c | awk 'BEGIN {cnt=0;FS=":"}; {cnt+=$2;}; END {print cnt;}'
```

Or use use awk regex directly:

```
awk 'BEGIN {cnt=0}; {if(/aaa/) {cnt+=1;}}; END {print cnt;}' aaa.txt bbb.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

As addition to the already given answer by **ghoti**:

You can avoid `awk -F:` by using `grep -h`:

```
grep -c -h -F "2016-08-30" applicationLog.log* | awk '{n+=$0} END {print n}'
```

This means no filenames and only the counts are printed by `grep` and we can use the first field for the addition in `awk`.

Comment: thanks! very useful when you only output numbers

Comment: in this answer I found that you can also use `jq -s 'add'` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26592910/1121497

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you:

```
grep -Eo "2016-08-30" applciationLog.log* -c | awk -F':' 'BEGIN {sum = 0;} {sum += $2;} END {print sum;}'
```

We use awk to split each line up with a delimeter of `:`, sum up the numbers for each line, and print the result at the end.

Comment: Nice answer!  ;-)  FYI, awk doesn't require semicolons *at the end of each command*, it only requires them for separation if multiple lines within the same statement are on the same line. So all the semicolons in your awk script can be dropped.

Comment: @ghoti Understood, made it as plain and verbose as possible to make it potentially easier to follow for someone unfamiliar with awk

Answer (score 0):

The `grep` command doesn't do arithmetic, it just finds lines that match regular expressions.

To count the output you already have, I'd use `awk`.

```
grep -c -F "2016-08-30" applciationLog.log* | awk -F: '{n+=$2} END {print n}'
```

Note that your `grep` options didn't make sense -- `-E` tells the command to use Extended regular expressions, but you're just looking for a fixed string (the date). So I swapped in the `-F` option instead. And `-o` tells grep to print the matched text, which you've overridden with `-c`, so I dropped it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using for-loop and arithmetic expansion could be:

```
x=0
for i in $(grep -hc "2016-08-30" applciationLog.log*);do
    x=$((x+i))
done
echo "$x"
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy alternative is to merge all the files before `grep` sees them:

```
cat applciationLog.log* | grep -Eo "2016-08-30" -c
```

Answer (score 0):

In my directory have have hundreds of files, each file contains lot of text along with a lines similar to this-

`Job_1-Run.log:[08/27/20 01:28:40] Total Jobs Cancelled for Job_1_set0 = 10`

I do
`grep '^Total Jobs Cancelled' ./*`
to get that above line.

Then I do a pipe
`| awk 'BEGIN {cnt=0;FS="="}; {cnt+=$2;}; END {print cnt;}'`

so my final command is-

`grep '^Total Jobs Cancelled' ./* | awk 'BEGIN {cnt=0;FS="="}; {cnt+=$2;};END {print cnt;}'`

and result is the sum. e.g. -
`900`

I am using Cmder @ https://cmder.net/

Thanks to the answer by @alagner, @john above