# Linux: get the last number of each line with a certain pattern and add those numbers up and save it as a variable

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to be able to write a command that will get the last numbers of each platform and add them up then save that number as a variable. For example, for "AIX" in the below random file, I want to be able to extract 1 and 115 and save 116 as a variable. Then for "Linx" I would want to save 2, 16, 18, 96 and 1 and save the sum as another variable.

```
cat randomfile.txt:

AIX,5.5.3-0,1
AIX,6.2.1-0,115
Linux x86-64,6.4.0-0,2
Linux x86-64,6.4.0-1,16
Linux x86-64,7.1.2-0,18
Linux86,6.1.3-4,96
Linux86,6.2.5-0,1
```

I was able to use "cat randomfile.txt | egrep "Linux" ", to specify only Linux lines although I need a way to print the last numbers of each line so I can save them into a variable and then add them up and save them as one variable.

Comment: Take it here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/ You'll get the perfect answer in no time flat.

Comment: why `Linux x86-64` and `Linux86` are treated as same?

Answer (score 2):

You can use to go at this file:

```
variable1=$(awk -F, '$1=="AIX"{aixsum+=$NF} END{print aixsum}' file)
variable2=$(awk -F, '$1~/^Linux/{linuxsum+=$NF} END{print linuxsum}' file)
```

That first one splits each record by comma and tests the first field. If it's equal to "AIX" it will sum up the last field into awk variable `aixsum`. Once it's processed the file it will spit out the result with that `END{}` block.

The second one works similar but uses regex for the search and finds any record where the first field starts with "Linux" and sums up the last fields, printing it once it has read the entire file.

Answer (score 1):

How about awk to an array?:

```
$ a=($(awk -F, '{sub(/[ 0-9].*/,"",$1);a[$1]+=$3}END{for(i in a)print i "=" a[i]}' file))
$ echo ${a[0]}
AIX=116
$ echo ${a[1]}
Linux=133
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
> numbers=$(grep Linux randomfile.txt | cut -d, -f3)
> sum=$(( ${numbers//$'\n'/+} ))
> echo $sum
133
```

`grep` provides the matching lines (`Linux`,`AIX`, …) and the `cut` command returns the numbers after the second comma.
Then the pattern `/$'\n'` is used to replace every newline in the `$numbers` variable with `+` giving `2+16+18+96+1` for `Linux`.

Then arithmetic expansion `$((…))` is used to evaluate that summation and store the result in `$sum`.

(see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/13969439/4832389)