# API to retrieve Google API usage

Tags: google-api

I am looking for a Google REST endpoint or SDK that will report the quota usage of a specific project and Google API. For example, if I write a query like

```
{
  "project": "my-project",
  "api": "searchconsole.googleapis.com",
  "function": "/urlInspection/index:inspect"
}
```

it will return the quota usage for that API, e.g.

```
{
  "qpd": {
    "used": 20,
    "limit": 200
  }
}
```

I've found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49543773/how-to-check-the-quota-limit-in-google-cloud-vision-api/) from 2018 that uses a `timeseries` query to *monitoring.googleapis.com*, but it seems "hacky" and as it's old, I'm wondering if there's a better way. I tried looking into https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp but as I  have no prior experience with monitoring, the documentation is confusing.