# How to display the sum of a column?

Tags: bash, awk

How can I find the sum of this column from a file named `cars`?

```
73
60
45
102
15
50
115
30
10
180
85
25
```

How can I add these numbers up (using the command line)?
I showed this list typing

```
awk '{ print $4 }' cars
```

Comment: You may shoot again after trying something with `sum += $4;` and `print sum`.

Comment: More exactly `awk '{sum += $4} END{print sum}'` and also the word you want for items or figures arranged vertically is _column_ -- _coulomb_ is a unit of electrical charge equal to 1 ampere for 1 second.

Comment: Possible related question [Shell command to sum integers, one per line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450799/shell-command-to-sum-integers-one-per-line)

Comment: Bulk down votes happened :( for all posts

Comment: Yeah, it'll be @jww up to his wacky tricks. I'll upvote all the answers to compensate.

Answer (score 3):

Given:

```
$ cat file
73
60
45
102
15
50
115
30
10
180
85
25
```

You can do:

```
$ paste -sd+ file | bc
790
```

Or, given a multi column file:

```
$ cat file
0   73  1
2   60  3
4   45  5
6   102 7
8   15  8
9   50  10
11  115 12
13  30  14
15  10  16
17  180 18
19  85  20
21  25  22
```

You can use `cut` to get the column of interest:

```
$ cut -f 2 file | paste -sd+ - | bc
790
```

Answer (score 0):

***1st Solution in awk:*** Could you please try following once.(I am taking sum of column 4 since your attempt shows it, had written a dynamic command where you need to change only variable's value and it will take that column's SUM then)

```
awk -v column_number=4 '{sum+=$column_number} END{print "SUM of column " column_number " is: " sum}'  Input_file
```

By running above code you could give any column number in variable `column_number` and could take some of it. In case you have any other requirement then kindly do show us sample input and expected sample output in code tags in your post.

***Explanation of above code:***

```
awk -v column_number=4 '    ##Starting awk program here and setting variable column_number value to 4 you could change it as per your column number too, for which you want to take SUM for all lines of Input_file.
{                           ##Starting a BLOCK here.
  sum+=$column_number       ##Creating a variable named SUM whose value is value of current lines $column_number value and it keep adding SUMs value to its own to get cumulative sum of all columns in all lines.
}                           ##Closing BLOCK here.
END{                        ##Mentioning awk program END block here, it will be executed when an Input_file is being done with reading.
  print "SUM of column " column_number " of all lines in Input_file is: " sum     ##Printing SUM variable value here.
}'  Input_file              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

***2nd Solution in bash:*** Considering that your lines in Input_file have only 1 entry.

```
while read line; do    sum=$(($sum+$line)) ; done < "Input_file"; echo "$sum"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it on command line, but not awk.

```
vim /tmp/text
let sum=0
for X in `cat /tmp/text`; do let sum=$sum+$X; done
echo $sum
```

Comment: though I have not given down vote here. IMHO you need not to read Input_file in every iteration of `for` loop you could see this link where we could use loop in bash to get sum once too https://stackoverflow.com/a/53688677/5866580