# Shell command to sum up numbers across similar lines of text in a file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a file with thousands of lines, each containing a number followed by a line of text. I'd like to add up the numbers for the lines whose text is similar. I'd like unique lines to be output as well.

For example:

```
25 cup of coffee
75 sign on the dotted
28 take a test
2 take a test
12 cup of coffee
```

The output would be:

```
37 cup of coffee
75 sign on the dotted
30 take a test
```

Any suggestions how this could be achieved in unix shell?

I looked at [Shell command to sum integers, one per line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450799/shell-command-to-sum-integers-one-per-line) but this is about summing up a column of numbers across all lines in a file, not across similar text lines only.

Comment: Do you need to keep the order ?

Comment: Keeping the order is not needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for multiple processes and pipes. `awk` alone is more than capable of handling the entire job (and will be orders of magnitude faster on large files). With `awk` simply append each of the fields `2-NF` as a string and use that as an index to sum the numbers in field 1 in an array. Then in the `END` section, simply output the contents of the array, e.g. presuming your data is stored in `file`, you could do:

```
awk '{
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
        str = str " " $i
    a[str] += $1
    str=""
}
END {
    for (i in a) print a[i], i
}' file
```

Above, the first `for` loop simply appends all fields from `2-NF` in `str`, `a[str] += $1` sums the values in field 1 into array `a` using `str` as an index. That ensures the values for similar lines are summed. In the `END` section, you simply loop over each element of the array outputting the element value (the sum) and then the index (original `str` for fields `2-NF`).

**Example Use/Output**

Just take what is above, select it, and then middle-mouse paste it into a command line in the directory where your `file` is located (change the name of `file` to your data file name)

```
$ awk '{
>     for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
>         str = str " " $i
>     a[str] += $1
>     str=""
> }
> END {
>     for (i in a) print a[i], i
> }' file
30  take a test
37  cup of coffee
75  sign on the dotted
```

If you want the lines sorted in a different order, just add `| sort [options]` after the filename to pipe the output to `sort`. For example for output in the order you show, you would use `| sort -k 2` and the output would be:

```
37  cup of coffee
75  sign on the dotted
30  take a test
```

**Preserving Original Order Of Strings**

Pursuant to your comment regarding how to preserve the original order of the lines of text seen in your input file, you can keep a second array where the strings are stored in the order they are seen using a sequential index to keep them in order. For example the `o` array (order array) is used below to store the unique string (fields `2-NF`) and the variable `n` is used as a counter. A loop over the array is used to check whether the string is already contained, and if so, `next` is used to avoid storing the string and jump to the next record of input. In `END` the loop then uses a `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)` form to output the information from both arrays in the order the string were seen in the original file, e.g.

```
awk -v n=0 '{
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
        str = str " " $i
    a[str] += $1
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (o[i] == str) {
            str=""
            next;
        }
    o[n++] = str;
    str=""
}
END {
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) print a[o[i]], o[i]
}' file
```

**Output**

```
37  cup of coffee
75  sign on the dotted
30  take a test
```

Comment: How to maintain the order of appearance of text (key), while populating / printing array.

Comment: To preserve the original text (key) order you can use a separate array using sequential numbered indexes to store `str` in the order seen, like `order[n++] = str;` Then in `END` you can loop over the second array in-order (e.g. `for (i = 0; i < n; i++) print a[order[i]], order[i]`) to preserve the original text order.

Comment: I tested this solution on my data with thousands of lines and it worked really well, really fast.

Comment: Glad it helped. An `awk` solution alone will always be more efficient than a combination of shell utilities strung together in a script or with pipes.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`datamash`](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/) is relatively succinct.  First use `sed` to change the first space to a tab, (for this job `datamash` must have one and only one tab separator), then use `-s -g2` to sort groups by the 2nd field, (*i.e.* "cup" *etc.*), then use `sum 1` to add up the first column numbers by group, and it's done.  No, not quite  -- the number column migrated to the *2nd* field for some reason, so `reverse` migrates it back to the *1st* field:

```
sed 's/ /\t/' file | datamash -s -g2 sum 1 | datamash reverse
```

Output:

```
37  cup of coffee
75  sign on the dotted
30  take a test
```

Comment: Brilliant. I wasn't aware of datamash. It's so easy to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple `awk` script that do the task:

`script.awk`

```
{                          # for each input line
    inpText = substr($0, length($1)+2);  # read the input text after 1st field
    inpArr[inpText] = inpArr[inpText] + 0 + $1; # accumulate the 1st field in array
}
END {                     # post processing
    for (i in inpArr) {   # for each element in inpArr
        print inpArr[i], i; # print the sum and the key
    }
}
```

`input.txt`

```
25 cup of coffee
75 sign on the dotted
28 take a test
2 take a test
12 cup of coffee
```

running:

```
awk -f script.awk input.txt
```

output:

```
75 sign on the dotted
37 cup of coffee
30 take a test
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following (assume the name of the file is file.txt):

```
for key in $(sort -k2  -u file.txt   | cut -d ' ' -f2)
do 
    cat file.txt|grep $key  | awk '{s+=$1} END {print $2 "\t" s}'
done
```

Explanation:
1. get all unique keys (cup of coffee, sign on the dotted, take a test):

```
sort -k2  -u file.txt   | cut -d ' ' -f2
```

2. grep all lines with unique key from the file:

```
cat file.txt | grep $key
```

3. Sum the lines using awk where $1=number column and $2 = key

```
awk '{s+=$1} END {print $2 "\t" s}'
```

4. Put everything in for loop and iterate over the unique keys

Note: If a key can be a sub-string of another key, for example "coffee" and "cup of coffee" you will need to change step 2 to grep with regex

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash

# define a dictionary
declare -A dict

# loop over all lines
while read -r line; do

   # read first word as value and the rest as text
   IFS=' ' read value text <<< "$line"

   # use 'text' as key, get value for 'text', default 0
   [ ${dict[$text]+exists} ] && dictvalue="${dict[$text]}" || dictvalue=0

   # sum value

   value=$(( $dictvalue + value )) 

   # save new value in dictionary
   dict[$text]="$value" 
done < data.txt  

# loop over dictionary, print sum and text
for key in "${!dict[@]}"; do
   printf "%s %s\n" "${dict[$key]}" "$key"
done
```

**output**

```
37 cup of coffee
75 sign on the dotted
30 take a test
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version based on the same logic as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56887386) @David.
Changes: It omits loops to speed up the process.

```
awk '
{
  text=substr($0, index($0,$2))
  if(!(text in text_sums)){ texts[i++]=text }
  text_sums[text]+=$1
}
END {
 for (i in texts) print text_sums[texts[i]],texts[i] 
}' input.txt
```

Explanation:
`substr` returns the string starting with field 2. i.e. text part
array `texts` stores text on integer index, if its not present in `text_sums` array.
`text_sums` keep adding field 1 for a corresponding text.

Reason behind a separate array to store text as value backed by consecutive integer as index, is to assures the order of value (text) while accessing in same consecutive order.

See [Array Intro](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Intro.html)

Footnotes says:

> The ordering will vary among awk implementations, which typically use hash tables to store array elements and values.