# How to use Grep commands to find specific value in text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

I need to grep a file called daily_fails_count.csv but only find the number of failures.
Inside that file is this, on a shorter scale:

```
January,1,0,0
January,1,1,0
January,1,2,0
January,1,3,0
January,1,4,0
January,1,5,0
January,1,6,0
January,1,7,0
January,1,8,0
```

It's format is "month,day,hours,failures." It goes through all months. The last value is the number of failures found at that time. I know here it all says 0 but that's because no failures were found there, other dates have failures.

I'm not very good with grep commands in Linux scripts, so my question is this, how do I grep to find just the last digit in the file?

I'm writing this script in a file called make_accum_fail_counts.sh and I will run it as such:

```
bash make_accum_fail_counts.sh daily_fail_counts.csv > accum_fail_counts.csv
```

So I'm using the daily_fail_counts.csv as the input for the new script. Here's my script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# == 1 ]
then
    logFile=$1
fi

cat $logFile > tmpFile

hour=0
failure=0

while [ $hour -le 23 ]
do
    if [ $hour -le 23 ]
    then
        failure=`grep "*,*,*,^[0-10]" tmpFile | wc -l`
    fi
    echo "$hour,$failure"
    hour=$((hour+1))
    failure=0
done
rm -rf tmpFile
```

I just need help with my grep command:

```
failure=`grep "*,*,*,^[0-10]" tmpFile | wc -l`
```

Just to find, among all the days, the failures from hour to hour. so it's output would be:

```
0,1000
1,1040
2,2888
```

Where there were 1000 failures between 0:00-1:00, 1040 failures between 1:00-2:00 and so on. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there are no spaces after the last digit, `grep -ohE '[[:digit:]]$' YOURFILE` would do. However, what does the last digit tell you? If the number of errors is `10`, the last digit is `0`, which is the same like no errors.  If all line have the exact same structure, `cut -d ',' -f 4 YOURFILE` would give you just the last number of each line, which perhaps would be more useful. Or you use with grep the pattern `[[:digit:]]+$`, which also returns the last number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat yourfile.csv | cut -d',' -f 4 | paste -s -d+ - | bc
```

To sum all the failures. Use `cut -d',' -f 4 yourfile.csv` to split each line on the commas and get the 4th value, that'll give you a list of numbers, then  [use a shell command to sum a list of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/450799/3064538).

You can grep to filter it down to the hour, something like

```
cat yourfile.csv | cut -d',' -f 3,4 | grep ^0, | cut -d',' -f 2
```

To get all the 0th hour failure counts.

```
for hour in {0..23}; do
    cat yourfile.csv | cut -d',' -f 3,4 | grep ^$hour, | cut -d',' -f 2 | paste -s -d+ - | bc
done
```

To get the totals for each hour.

If you want them grouped by day you can read about the `date` command, figure out how to get it to output strings like `January,1,` and and add an outer `for` loop to the above command that passes each line through a `grep` with the output of that `date` command.

Personally, at this point I would start writing Python instead of bash. The `pandas` library is better suited for this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, could you please try following. This will provide total of failures(last field/4th field) count as per hours values and irrespective of month.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
!b[$3]++{
  c[++count]=$3
}
{
  a[$3]+=$4
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print c[i],a[c[i]]
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

1 more thing, this approach will provide output in same order in which `$3` is coming in Input_file.

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code here.

```
awk '                          ##Starting awk program here.
BEGIN{                         ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  FS=OFS=","                   ##Setting FS and OFS as comma here.
}                              ##Closing BLOCK for BEGIN section here.
!b[$3]++{                      ##Checking condition if $3 is NOT present in array b then do following + it is placing $3 in array b.
  c[++count]=$3                ##Creating an array named c whose index is variable count and value is $3, variable count value is keep increasing with 1.
}                              ##Closing BLOCK for array b condition here.
{
  a[$3]+=$4                    ##Creating an array named a with index $3 and value is $4 and its keep adding its value to its own same index value.
}
END{                           ##Starting END section of this program here.
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){       ##Starting for loop from i=1 to till value of count variable here.
    print c[i],a[c[i]]         ##Printing array c value index variable i and printing array a value whose index is array c with index variable i.
  }                            ##Closing BLOCK for, for loop here.
}                              ##Closing BLOCK for END section of this program here.
'  Input_file                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with awk, is there any way to simply use grep to count the failures?

Comment: @Tristan, Trust me `awk` will be much easier, and it comes by default in servers. it will be a difficult task for `grep` and you may need to use come other tools with it too, lemme know if any queries please?

Comment: @Tristan, I have added explanation for your understanding too now.