# using ffprobe to count number of audio channels in a video file

Tags: ffprobe

I am using this to get the number of audio channels in a video file:

```
ffprobe -i movie.mxf -show_entries stream=channels -select_streams a -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -v 0
```

Which outputs:

> 0
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1

There are 8 audio channels, and I wanted to get that number as a variable. Is this possible?

Comment: You're displaying channels per stream. You'll have to sum them yourself.

Comment: I would count the number of 1s in the output string?

Comment: Yes, if you want to count the total number of channels of all audio streams. See `paste` answer in [Shell command to sum integers, one per line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/451204/)