# see how many cores per user

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm

I am using the job scheduler [SLURM](https://slurm.schedmd.com/).

It is possible to [get information about CPU usage by Jobs/Steps/Tasks](https://slurm.schedmd.com/cpu_management.html#Section2) but how to have access to the number of cores a user is currently using ?

The list of jobs of a specific user `user_name` can be obtained with: `squeue | grep user_name` and the number of jobs currently running with: `squeue | grep user_name | wc -l`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the output of `squeue` with `--user=...` and set `squeue` to only display the number of CPUs with `-o%C`.

```
$ squeue -hu user_name -o "%C" 
24
24
1
1
1
1
```

From there, use your [preferred method for summing those numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450799/shell-command-to-sum-integers-one-per-line), for instance

```
$ squeue -hu user_name -o "%C" | paste -d + -s | bc
52
```